# Git: cannot checkout branch - error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git

I'm not sure why I'm **unable to checkout** a branch that I had worked on earlier. See the commands below (note: `co` is an alias for `checkout`):

```
ramon@ramon-desktop:~/source/unstilted$ git branch -a
* develop
  feature/datts_right
  feature/user_controlled_menu
  feature/user_controlled_site_layouts
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/feature/datts_right
  remotes/origin/master
ramon@ramon-desktop:~/source/unstilted$ git co feature/user_controlled_site_layouts 
error: pathspec 'feature/user_controlled_site_layouts' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I'm not sure what it means, and I can't seem to find anything I can understand on Google.

**How do I checkout that branch, and what may I have done to break this?**

**UPDATE**:

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/git-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any), and running `git show-ref` gives me:

```
97e2cb33914e763ff92bbe38531d3fd02408da46 refs/heads/develop
c438c439c66da3f2356d2449505c073549b221c1 refs/heads/feature/datts_right
11a90dae8897ceed318700b9af3019f4b4dceb1e refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_menu
c889b37a5ee690986935c9c74b71999e2cf3c6d7 refs/heads/master
c889b37a5ee690986935c9c74b71999e2cf3c6d7 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
e7c17eb40610505eea4e6687e4572191216ad4c6 refs/remotes/origin/develop
c438c439c66da3f2356d2449505c073549b221c1 refs/remotes/origin/feature/datts_right
c889b37a5ee690986935c9c74b71999e2cf3c6d7 refs/remotes/origin/master
23768aa5425cbf29d10ff24274adad42d90d15cc refs/stash
e572cf91e95da03f04a5e51820f58a7306ce01de refs/tags/menu_shows_published_only
429ebaa895d9d41d835a34da72676caa75902e3d refs/tags/slow_dev
```

**UPDATE on `.git` directory** (`user_controlled_site_layouts` is in the `refs/heads/feature folder`):

```
$ ls .git/refs/heads/feature/
datts_right  user_controlled_menu  user_controlled_site_layouts
$ cat .git/refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layouts
3af84fcf1508c44013844dcd0998a14e61455034
```

**UPDATE on `git show 3af84fcf1508c44013844dcd0998a14e61455034`**

```
$ git show 3af84fcf1508c44013844dcd0998a14e61455034
commit 3af84fcf1508c44013844dcd0998a14e61455034
Author: Ramon Tayag <xxx@xxxxx.xxx>
Date:   Thu May 12 19:00:03 2011 +0800

    Removed site layouts migration

diff --git a/db/schema.rb b/db/schema.rb
index 1218fc8..2040b9f 100755
--- a/db/schema.rb
+++ b/db/schema.rb
@@ -10,7 +10,7 @@
 #
 # It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

-ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110511012647) do
+ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110503040056) do

   create_table "attachments", :force => true do |t|
     t.string   "name"
@@ -205,15 +205,6 @@ ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110511012647) do
     t.integer  "old_id"
   end

-  create_table "site_layouts", :force => true do |t|
-    t.string   "name"
-    t.text     "description"
-    t.text     "content"
-    t.integer  "site_id"
-    t.datetime "created_at"
-    t.datetime "updated_at"
-  end
-
   create_table "site_styles", :force => true do |t|
     t.text     "published"
     t.datetime "created_at"
```

Comment: Might this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527355/using-the-slash-character-in-git-branch-name

Comment: Does it work if you do: `git checkout refs/heads/user_controlled_site_layouts`?

Comment: Boldewyn - thanks, but it didn't help. But I've edited the question to show what's in the `.git/refs` folder.

Comment: Mark - nope, still get the same error.

Comment: Seeing your update, I'm not sure how you've got a branch that appears in `git branch -a` but not in `git show-ref`.  Does the file `.git/refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layout` actually exist?  If so, what does `cat .git/refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layout` give?

Comment: Mark, I've updated it with the contents of `.git/refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layouts`.

Comment: Did you try `git checkout feature/user_controlled_site_layouts --`? (You might want to avoid naming branches with slashes in them - hyphens are perhaps a good replacement.)

Comment: Jefromi, I first started using slashes when I implemented git-flow (http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/). It doesn't seem to be a problem for them. I also read that slashes aren't a problem (don't remember where). Here's the response to the command you pasted: `fatal: invalid reference: feature/user_controlled_site_layouts`.

Comment: Branch names with slashes are fine. It is suspicious that `git branch -a` shows your problematic branch, yet `git show-ref` does not. I can induce this problem by introducing an “invisible” character (I used NUL, ASCII 0) anywhere in the first 40 bytes of a loose ref file. The contents of the file look fine with `cat`, it shows up in `git branch -a`, but the branch is dropped from `git show-ref` (and `git branch -av` gives an error: `error: branch 'whatever' does not point at a commit`). Try `od -a .git/refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layouts`. Anything besides 0-9a-f + NL?

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer have the git repo available. After a while of not being able to solve this, I think I just ended up forgoing the work in that branch. The solution would not have fixed mine anyway (I think) -- I never pushed the branch to a remote repo.

Comment: I'm getting this same error. The only thing I can think of is that I'm on a Lustre parallel filesystem. I've had things behave oddly before, usually dealing with unsupported file locking features. Are you on Lustre?

Comment: I was not on Lustre. I was on Ubuntu or OSX -- don't remember which.

Comment: 30 Solutions collect form web for “Git: cannot checkout branch – error: pathspec '…' did not match any file(s) known to git”
http://gitbaby.com/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-known-to-git.html

Comment: Make sure you're in the correct directory relative to the file you want to checkout.

Comment: I got the same error, I created the branch from another repo and try to checkout that branch to another repo. So I got it because of the different repos.

Comment: Seems that this issue is in git bash only; **It's working fine in SourceTree**.

Comment: The most important check is that you are pointing to the correct repo. I got lots of complain about this error and it turns out that the user was pointing to REPOB when is suppose to point to REPOA. The Remote repo that was standarized was REPOA. 
first smoke test to be sure...

Comment: As of [October 1, 2020](https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-main-starting-next-month/#:~:text=GitHub%20repositories%20are%20where%20users,of%20a%20source%20code%20repository.&text=1%2C%202020%2C%20any%20new%20repositories,master%2C%22%20the%20company%20said.), GitHub changed the name of the master branch to "main" to avoid negative connotations. `git checkout main` should work.

Comment: for < 0.001 % try default cloning and then checking out whatever branch. It wasn't working for me when i had cloned a specific branch and had added multiple remote.

Comment: It happened to me when my working directory was a submodule!

Comment: It happened to me in windows, running a for loop  under git bash. The branch name had a \r\n with the \r causing the issue. once i changed the EOL to just \n, it worked fine

Comment: FYI looks like github changed the name of the primary branch from 'master' to 'main' recently (2021)

Comment: `git pull origin <branchName>` works for me

Answer (score 1543):

Try `git fetch` so that your local repository gets all the new info from Github. It just takes the information about new branches and no actual code. After that, the `git checkout` should work fine.

Comment: For further clarification, `git fetch` is useful when you need to synchronize your local repository with the remote repository, but you *don't* want to merge the changes into your working folder.

Comment: In case of a clone with multiple remotes, the `git checkout Branch` does not work. With multiple remotes just the Branch name is ambiguous and requires the specification of remote/branch. The command `git checkout -b branch remote/branch` works in that scenario.

Comment: I had managed to create a local "master" somehow, so although "git fetch" got me closer, I had to delete my local master first ("git branch -d master"), before switching to the remote master ("git checkout master").  In case that helps anyone else who is as silly as me!

Comment: There is also a command like `git remote add origin ssh://...` which you can use if your local master branch is not tracking the remote one.

Comment: Some clarifications on @UmairIshaq comment, the reason `git checkout Branch` does not work is only if that branch exists in the clones. `git` is smart enough to still checkout a branch from a clone as long as that branch only is not cloned anywhere else.  Ex. branch: 'site_layout' lives on remote 'example' and nowhere else, `git checkout site_layout` will produce a local branch that is tracking on `example/site_layout`

Comment: @ Aleks it's not the accepted answer because it has **nothing** to do with the OP's question. He could no longer check out a branch **he'd previously checked out (ie created) locally**. Just because other people with a different, much more basic problem have found & upvoted this answer (which is completely trivial and well-known to any git user with more than two days experience) doesn't mean the OP should accept it.

Comment: `git fetch` could do the job. But it may fail to get all the branches from remote. You'd need to set the fetch match pattern.
`git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"` refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches

Comment: git fetch is a bizarre and crazy thing, and it takes more than 2 days to learn about these crazy little tarpits.

Comment: I have got this error on windows when I set commit message in '' not "" for an example `git commit  -m "Marats version"` works fine, but `git commit  -m 'Marats version'` isnt

Comment: Maybe you dont have a branch so you encountered this problem. you can check are there this branch ? and then you write > git checkout -b branchname

Comment: For me, git reset . worked

Comment: `git pull origin <banchName>` 
worked for me.

Answer (score 487):

I was getting this error when I tried to checkout new branch:

> error: pathspec 'BRANCH-NAME' did not match any file(s) known to git.

When I tried `git checkout origin/<BRANCH-NAME>`, I got the detached HEAD:

> (detached from origin/)

**Finally, I did the following to resolve the issue**:

```
git remote update
git fetch 
git checkout --track origin/<BRANCH-NAME>
```

Comment: with this "checkout" command I have this message:
_fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'foo' at the same time._

Comment: After manually modifying the remote address, I could not checkout new branches. "git remote update" seemed to do the trick.

Comment: without the "git remote update" it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: `git checkout --track origin/staging
fatal: git checkout: --track and --no-track require -b` git version 1.5.6.5

Comment: Used next instead third command `git checkout -b staging --track origin/staging`

Comment: git fetch origin <branch name> finally made it work for me.

Comment: For me `git fetch` alone didn't work, but this solution (that includes `remote update` and `track origin` works perfectly.

Comment: If none of these work, check to make sure that the branch has actually been pushed to the remote repo.

Comment: It worked but what caused this error? Can you elaborate pls

Comment: Having tried all other solutions, none of them worked for me. Finally this one works for me. Thank you!!
I think the key is to do 
`git remote update`

Comment: `git remote update` worked for me too. But do we know why we have to do that? Isn't git fetch supposed to work (has worked on all of my other repos).

Answer (score 173):

I got this error for a branch that was remote and had no local tracking branch. Even though I'm certain I've checked out remote branches via a simple

```
git checkout feature/foo
```

in the past, to get around this error I had to

```
git checkout -t -b feature/foo origin/feature/foo
```

I have no idea what I did to get myself into that situation either.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't push it to the remote git server.

Comment: This worked for me. It happened on git v 1.6 on FC10 machine.

Comment: Git usually guesses the remote branch to check out, but when using more than one remote, it seems like it no longer can do that. Source: http://makandracards.com/makandra/14323-git-how-to-check-out-branches-that-exist-on-multiple-remotes

Comment: doing git checkout feature/foo instead of just git checkout foo worked for me

Comment: this started happening to me (in a repo with many remotes and hundreds of branches from which I'd been successfully checking out branches from origin for 3 years) and I was mystified. Upon inspection, I discovered I'd added a new remote and I'd done it in with copy/paste in a text editor instead of using the git command, and forgot to change the `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` line to match the new remote name. LOL. Maybe this happened to makandra? because after fixing it, checking out branch once again gets it from origin, even though I have many remotes.

Comment: Doesn't passing `-b- create a new branch? Does it create a new local branch which tracks the remote branch, or could this command create a new remote branch?

Comment: Yes it creates a new *local* branch that mirrors/tracks the existing remote branch.

Comment: I had the exact same problem as the above answer (suddenly couldn't check out remote branches).  Turns out I had added `guess = false` to my `.gitconfig` while trying to solve another issue.  Removing that fixed my problem.

Answer (score 138):

If you deleted a branch with `git branch -D yourbranchname` and pulled/cloned again your repo, you may need to create your local branch again.

Try:

```
git checkout -b yourbranchname
```

Comment: this option always works, even where is files already changed and u wish to push them to newly created branch.

Comment: This was a helpful comment because while I shared the same problem/question as the OP here, the answers provided assumed a straightforward situation. Unfortunately, in my situation, I had previously created ONLY a local branch, then deleted it as noted here by @Francisco Alvarez, so no matter how I tried the other solutions here, I could not pull the new remote branch. This answer saved my bacon.

Comment: this finally worked for me with un-editable jenkins configurations, thanks! (they are autogenerated by other DSL)

Comment: Thanks a lot. i have been trying all other ways.. but this really worked.

Comment: This way very simple and it worked for me.

Answer (score 135):

I have the same questions, and got some information from this link: [git fetch doesn't fetch all branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623862/git-fetch-doesnt-fetch-all-branches)

So now, I may not sure how this situation happened, at least we can solve it:

**Step 1.** Check your "remote.origin.fetch" setting, should be like this

> $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
>
> +refs/heads/private_dev_branch:refs/remotes/origin/private_dev_branch

**Step 2.** Change "remote.origin.fetch" to fetch everything

> $ git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
>
> $ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
>
> +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

Then, you can try "git pull" (maybe "git fetch origin" also works but I didn't try) to get all the branch.

Comment: @onionjake is right, sorry that I didn't check the questions in every details. Just I got the same error messages while trying the same action of "git checkout <existed_branch>", but different from the originator's problem actually----- originator could see the branch locally while I cannot. My answer may solve the problem for whom didn't fetch all branches in advanced. But not the situation for originator's problem.

Comment: Many people including me receive this error, because they could clone a repo with --branch flag, therefore, even after git fetch they don't get other branches and can't checkout anything from remote. This fixes this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using tensorflow's devel docker image, and it restricts the branch to certain version. After setting up fetch config, now I can checkout.

Comment: Tks, solution my problem.

Comment: Thanks! 'git config remote.origin.fetch "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"' just saved my life!

Comment: Upvoting this since it helped me (esp since I forgot that I had cloned branch at first). And this is the second or third link on google for the error message that git gives.

Answer (score 49):

I had the same issue for one of my branch.

These commands work for me.

```
git fetch --all
git checkout <branch-name>
```

Answer (score 46):

Just do a `git fetch origin <branchName>:<branchName>`.

This will fetch and create a local copy of the same hence now you can

checkout into it `git checkout <branchName>`

Comment: Interesting solution, but it's got a weakness. I just tested it, and while it creates the local branch as desired, it doesn't set the upstream on it. For this to work as one would expect, you'd have to run `git branch -u origin/<branchName>` after doing your checkout.

Comment: I had to set the upstream by running `git push --set-upstream origin <branchName>` in order to be able to push changes.

Comment: `git pull origin <branchName>`
worked for me.

Answer (score 30):

Git Windows users beware - without the `--icase-pathspecs` or `GIT_ICASE_PATHSPECS = 1` [env var setting](http://git-scm.com/docs/git.html), that git pathspecs will be case-sensitive, in which case

```
git checkout origin/FooBranch "Some/Path/To/File.txt"
```

is not the same as

```
git checkout origin/FooBranch "some/path/to/file.Txt"
```

Comment: One thing to note that wasn't clear from documentation is that the `--icase-pathspecs` parameter needs to come first or at least before `-C <path>`

Answer (score 24):

If branch name and you dont have any uncommited file, then try this

```
git fetch && git checkout <branch name>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the question at all?

Comment: I got the same issue mentioned above, resolved using following commands

Answer (score 24):

I fixed it by modifying my git config file
Check your the config file in your git directory - `.git\config`

It previously had

```
[remote "origin"]
url = http://git.xyz.com/abc-group/pqr.git
fetch = +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/develop
```

I fixed by modifying it to

```
[remote "origin"]
url = http://git.xyz.com/abc-group/pqr.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Notice the head was pointing to only one branch, so it couldnt find the reference to other existing branches, I changed it to * so it checks everything in origin.

Comment: Thanks, buddy, hours of efforts and finally I landed with your solution.

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer

Comment: Thanks, only answer that helped me too. You can actually do:
`git config --local remote.origin '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'`

Answer (score 22):

I faced the issue while switching my branch.

I did a git pull on the current branch and then tried to checkout the new one and it worked

`git pull // on your old branch
git checkout <new_branch>`

Comment: Really useful:)

Comment: Why would this work? Does `git pull` do more than pull the current branch?

Comment: This might just be a case that you are trying to pull from a branch created by someone else and that's not yet pulled in your current repo.

Answer (score 18):

```
git pull
```

That simply fixed it for me :)

Comment: The reason WHY this worked for me is that I wanted to `git checkout master path/to/some/file.ext`, but my LOCAL master wasn't in sync with remote master because I had been on a development branch for a long time.

Answer (score 17):

I got this error when trying to checkout a branch via:

```
git checkout branchX
```

which I had not checked out before.
It only worked when explicitly stating the remote:

```
git checkout --track origin/branchX
```

The reason for this was, that I had 2 different remotes (origin + sth. else) configured in git config. As I didn't need the second remote, I removed it and voilá, it worked. The alternative to set the default remote via:

```
checkout.defaultRemote=origin
```

did not work for me

Comment: I added this answer because all the other suggested answers did not work for me, so I hope this helps someone who has the same cause (2 remotes).

Comment: This worked for me after I accidentally ran `git rm -f .git/index.lock` and then correctly ran `rm -f .git/index.lock` because I was getting `fatal: Unable to create '/home/sagemaker-user/qubed2/.git/index.lock': File exists.` from git gui shenanigans

Answer (score 16):

I got the same problem because I used `git clone --depth=1`, which implies `--single-branch`.

Do a completed `git clone` will fix it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It is exactly the same issue I was facing. Thanks

Comment: A complete clone might not be required. If the branch is created by someone else AFTER you originally cloned the repo, you get this error because your local repo does not have any information about this new branch. Just switch to master and do a git pull. Then try to checkout the new branch.

Comment: No need to do a complete `git clone`, if anyone is wondering. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27393574

Answer (score 14):

A better/simpler one:

```
git fetch origin yourLocalBranch:yourLocalBranch
git checkout yourLocalBranch
```

I got this error when I shallow clone a repo, and got it a solution
For example the branch I want to checkout is release/120

```
git ls-remote origin release/120 # make sure the remote branch exits
git fetch origin refs/heads/release/120:refs/remotes/origin/release/120 # fetch to local repo
git co -b release/120 origin/release/120 # checkout to workspace
```

Answer (score 13):

I got this when I did the following:

- Used IntelliJ IDE, connected to git
- Created a new file, and added to git
- Renamed the new file

When I tried to check in the directory, I got this error.

To fix:

I opened the repo in git extensions. I saw that the file (with the old name) was staged. But since it didnt exist anymore, it could not be committed.

I simply unstaged this file.

Then I re-added the file (this time correctly named) into git and committed without errors.

Comment: The funny thing is, it still works with TortoiseGit even if it does not in intellij

Comment: This helped me alot.
I used SourceTree to find that f**ck*r of a file and unstaged it.

Answer (score 10):

I copied remote origin `url` from another `.git/config` file, doing so my new `.git/config` file was missing following line in `[remote "origin"]` section

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Adding above line fixed `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem today I was trying to `git checkout foo` and got `error: pathspec 'foo' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

It turns out **I was in the wrong repo**. So lesson learned: check which repo you're looking at before freaking out.

Comment: Ha - yes this was me - created branch in Bitbucket from Jira ticket, didn't notice it created it in some random repo

Comment: sidenote: I was working with multiple remotes, had one set properly, and the other pointing to the wrong repo. sooo. thanks for the reminder, I could easily see my issue when I did a git remote -v

Comment: This was my problem too.  We had moved the location of the repo in gitlab, but I was still working from a previous checkout of it before the move.

Answer (score 9):

First, checkout parent branch.Then type

```
git fetch --all --prune 
git checkout <your branch>
```

Hope it helps!.

Comment: This works because of the `--all` -- I was receiving the error because I had 2 remotes, and one had fetched the new branch while the other hadn't. Either remove the second remote, or do `git fetch --all`

Answer (score 8):

I encountered this same issue when I was first playing around with git. When attempting my first commit...

```
git commit -m 'first commit!'
```

I got the error mentioned by the OP...

```
error: pathspec 'commit!'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I thought I might have been confusing git by using a keyword in the commit message, so I tried a few other words and received the same error.

Finally I used double-quotes in the message...

```
git commit -m "first commit!"
```

This turned out to be successful...

```
[master (root commit) 0000000] first commit!
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 dummyDoc.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

I had made a silly mistake of not providing -m flag while committing (lol happens)

```
git commit -m "commit message in here"
```

Comment: same situation here. just forget "-m" get the same error msg.

Answer (score 8):

Well, I had few deleted branches like *dev/{feature_branch}* and when I created a new branch *dev* and tried to checkout, I was getting the same issue. I ran the below command

```
git fetch -p
```

and worked for me.

Comment: I wonder why this worked? I initialized git locally, created a branch right away, added and commited files, then pushed it. Then tried to go to checkout to main - got the error: pathspec 'main' did not match any file(s) known to git . Ran this git fetch -p - it worked. I wonder if this is because it got updated remote references to main which it did not have before? Or likely when I initialized the repo with git init, it created a master branch - but when I created a repo on github there - its branch is main.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue.. I thought I had branch named `foo` when I try to:

```
git checkout foo
```

I was getting:

```
error: pathspec 'foo' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Then I tried the full branch name:

```
git checkout feature/foo
```

then worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

On Windows OS by default git is instaled with

```
core.ignorecase = true
```

This means that git repo files will be case insensitive, to change this you need to execute:

```
\yourLocalRepo> git config core.ignorecase false
```

you can find this configuration on **.git\config** file

Answer (score 6):

In my case I have TWO branch 1) master(which is for live server) 2) dev(test server). I had set multiple remote to push code on respective server. When I tried to switch branch I got the error like `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

You can see them by `git remote -v`.
I had removed other remote except `origin` remote by `git remote remove <remote-name>`

Then `git fetch`

Now I am able to checkout branch by `git checkout <branch-name>`.

Answer (score 6):

Three steps

1. Write a command 'git fetch'
2. then you will see the desired branch then switch to the relevant branch 'git checkout 'your_branch_name'
3. then write a command 'git pull origin your_desired_branch_name'

Answer (score 5):

If it happens on Windows, it is probably the filename case issue.

I had this error today - I've created new file, added to GIT, then I changed one letter in filename from lower to upper and then I couldn't to anything - commit, revert, delete file from repo.

The only solution I found was changing the filename again back to exact same case when I added this file to GIT, then doing GIT revert to remove this file from GIT, then changing filename again as I want. After those changes I could commit to repo and then push without any problem.

Comment: This helped, but it should be mentioned to do the renaming via `git mv`. Guess you've done it this way, because doing it via my IDE (IntelliJ PhpStorm) failed for me...

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me after renaming an uncommitted file in Android Studio.

Git seemed to have the old version in its repository, even if it didn´t exist anymore.

```
fetch, pull, checkout, add all and so on did not help in my case!
```

So I opened the Git GUI of TortoiseGit which showed me the exact file that caused trouble.

Afterwards I deleted the file from the repository with

```
git rm -r --cached /path/to/affected/file
```

and the problem was gone

Answer (score 5):

I had a different root cause

I had a script that basically searches all branches matching jira issue key in the for "PRJ-1234" among all branches to execute a git branch checkout command on the matching branch

The problem in my case was 2 or more branches shared the same jira key and hence caused my script to fail with the aforementioned error

By deleting the old unused branch and making sure only a single branch had the jira key reference fixed the problem

Here's my code in case someone wants to use it

```
git remote update
git fetch --all --prune 
git branch -r --list *$1* | xargs git checkout --force
```

save this as `switchbranch.sh`

Then use it from the terminal `./switchbranch.sh PRJ-1234`

Comment: For me, it was also the right upstream path/name and including to fetch all of the remote tags as well
     "git fetch --all --tags --prune"
 finding the right name:
     "git branch -a | grep some_upstream"
 before checking it out with the full path as
    "git checkout -f --track -b new_branch remotes/upstream/some_upstream_branch"

Answer (score 5):

This error did occur to me recently when I tried to checkout to my master branch with the below command.

> git checkout master

Since Github has changed the naming convention from ***`master`*** to ***`main`*** above command will give you the error. So instead of that, you may use the below command.

```
git checkout main
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had renamed a file changing the case of the file, i.e. 
  SomeFile.js -> someFile.js

I think that was related to the problem.  Doing a git fetch didn't fix the issue.

I moved the files out of my project, did a fetch, and did a push without them.  Then I did a fetch, added them back, and did a push, and it worked.  I don't know if all those steps were needed, but it did ultimately work.

Comment: Push without the renamed file and issuing git add file afterwards did it for me

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers solved my issue:

```
Nikolai@CALIGARI-7 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Version (master)
$ git log --format=oneline
b9cc6a9078312865280fb5432a43e17eff03a5c6 Formatted README
288772f36befe6bd60dd41b8185f1e24e0119668 Updated README documentation
d2bdbe18f4169358d46fad50eacfb89786df3bf8 Version object v3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
a46b1910a3f548b4fa254a6055d25f68d3f217dd VersionFactory is now Platform agnostic
24179ae569ec7bd28311389c0a7a85ea7b4f9594 Added internal.Platform abstraction
252b684417cf4edd71aed43a15da2c8a59c629a7 Added IPlugin implementation for Sponge
e3f8d21d6cf61ee4fc806791689c984c149b45e3 Added IPlugin implementation for Bukkit
aeb403914310b4b10dee9e980cf64472e2bfda79 Refactored Version.java
ef50efcff700c6438d57f70fac30846de2747a7e Refactored TesterFactory
a20808065878d4d28657ae362235c837cfa8e625 Added IPlugin abstraction
9712a3575a70060d7ecea8b62bb5e888fdc32d07 Heavily refactored Tester
02d025788ae740dbfe3ef76a132cea8ca4e47467 Added generic Predicate<T> interface
9c565777abea9be6767dfdab4ab94ed1173750dd Minor refactoring of testCompareTo()
2ff2a28c221681e256dcff28770782736d3a796a Version object v2.0.1
d4b2e2bd830f77cdbc2297112c2e46b6555d4393 Fix compareTo()
05fe7e012b07d1a5b8de29804f96d9a6b24229a1 Make compareTo() fail
6e85371414357a41c1fc0cec0e75adba92f96832 Fix VersionFactory passing null
c1fd1f032f87d860d5ed9d6f6679c9fa522cff8d Version object v2.0
62c3a92c008a2ed11f0a4d016080afc3541d0700 Version object v1.2
c42e9e617128085e872c51b4d977a04e48d69e8f Deprecated, doc'd, future-proofed getNm


Nikolai@CALIGARI-7 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Version (master)
$ git checkout 3a796a
error: pathspec '3a796a' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I was trying to go back and build the commit for `Version object v2.0.1`. Luckily, I got the idea to try the whole hash code and it worked ! Which means that I was using the wrong end of the hash code.

```
Nikolai@CALIGARI-7 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Version (master)
$ git checkout 2ff2a
Note: checking out '2ff2a'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 2ff2a28... Version object v2.0.1

Nikolai@CALIGARI-7 ~/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Version ((2ff2a28...))
$
```

As shown above, for partial hash codes, you must supply the front-end, not the back-end.

Answer (score 4):

check whether it is not a typo in the target file name. I was attempting to stage by typing

```
git add includes/connection..php
```

But I did not notice that I was using two dots 
But then I type

```
git add includes/connection.php
```

It works

Answer (score 4):

Such a problem arise when you try to get branch your local git doesn`t know.
First

```
git remote add origin yourremotegitrepository
```

After

```
git fetch //you should get all remote branches  

git checkout branchname
```

That is all.

Answer (score 3):

in my case I enter submodule directory without doing

- `git submodule init`
- `git submodule update`

So git was linked to the parent folder that indeed missed that branch.

Answer (score 3):

I was losing my mind over this issue, but then I've read the documentation and realised that my company has split their repo into multiple remotes, so some branches would be on the main remote and others would require you to fetch from a different remote.

Check whether the repo you're trying to checkout has one remote or multiple

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layouts
3af84fcf1508c44013844dcd0998a14e61455034
```

Can you confirm that the following works:

```
$ git show 3af84fcf1508c44013844dcd0998a14e61455034
```

It could be the case that someone has rewritten the history and that this commit no longer exists (for whatever reason really).

Comment: How could the commit no longer exist if it is referenced by that branch?

Comment: Magnus, I added the output of what you asked to my question.

Comment: This is indeed a weird problem. Does "git show-ref --verify refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layout" give you any more information as to what may be the problem?

Comment: I just get this `fatal: 'refs/heads/feature/user_controlled_site_layout' - not a valid ref`

Answer (score 2):

**For me, it was a problem with my credentials**

---

After trying some of the answer, one of them helped me to solve the problem:

Running `git fetch` threw the following error:

> Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org

All I had to do was force my IDE (VS Code in my case) to remember my credentials:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Git immediately synched all the changes, and `git checkout <branche>` works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

This problem may have been caused when doing a commit either without the commit message specified with `-m` or using single apostrophes `'` for the message in windows terminal:

Wrong:

`git commit "minor changes"`

`git commit -m 'minor changes'`

Correct:

`git commit -m "minor changes"`

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same `pathspec error` on git-bash. I used Tortoise git on windows to switch/checkout the branch.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused when upstream rewrites history.

When this happens, I toss all affected repos, clone them fresh from upstream, and use 'git format-patch' / 'git am' to ferry any work in progress from old world to new.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. What led me into this trouble was:
I had multiple remote branches and I deleted the folder that had the code.
I did a get pull. :

```
git pull git@git.corp......
```

Then I added remote repository :

```
git remote add upstream git@git.corp.......
```

Then I tried to change branch to some other branch say AAAA and I got error

```
error: pathspec 'AAAA' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

After spending an hour I found a solution.
I deleted the source folder again.
Then I did a git pull :

```
git pull git@git.corp......
```

Then I changed branch before linking it to remote repository :

```
git checkout AAA
```

then I added it to remote repository

```
git remote add upstream git@git.corp......
```

After this I can easily switch branches.
Although this is not a standard way but it worked for me after I tried all of above options.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when working with Git on Windows. In my case, it was a case issue.
I had already added and committed a file to my repository and later changed only its case. 
To solve the problem, I renamed the file to match the original case and rename it again with the `git mv` command. Appearently, this lets git track the rename.

Note: I was using Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem last time, and the thing I have done is remove the folder (or source code) related to that branch.

Ex: the branch origin/foo create folder foo at your local, so I just delete it and use `git fetch $ checkout` to get code back from remote.

Or you can do it by create folder at local same as the branch you intended to checkout.

Ex: create folder foo at local, after that, use Git command: `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/foo foo`, that all. Use `git pull` to get code.

Answer (score 1):

I my case I run "git fetch" before "git branch ...:, but obtained the same error.
Then I analyzed it and **found error in my branch name**. Fixed it and switch to branch successfully.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason, If you are working on **windows** machine with **MINGW***

```
ISSUE
```

Check the branch name you want to checkout.Windows **omits character** `'` from branch name while parsing command.

for example : if you have a branch name like `bugfix/some-'branch'-name`

When you issue command : `> git checkout bugfix/some-'branch'-name` it will parse it as `bugfix/some-branch-name`, notice it omits `'` character.

```
REMEDY
```

To checkout this kind of branch name, **add escape character** while issuing command.

Type : `> git checkout bugfix/some-\'branch\'-name`

It shoud work then!!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, there are too many answers already. But in my case, I faced this issue while I was working on Eclipse and using git-bash to switch between branches/checkouts. Once I closed the eclipse and relaunched the git-bash to checkout branch everything worked well.

So my suggestion for you to double check if your repository is not being used by another application.

Answer (score 1):

**I was getting the same error** because I was checking out the branch that was not existing . So we need to make sure that the branch that we are checking out exists in the repository.

Comment: This answer was already given.

Answer (score 1):

A possible reason for this issue might be lack of synchronization between a local repository and its upstream repository too. In this case, a simple `git pull upstream <branch_name>` followed by a `git checkout <branch_name>` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Tried all recommended solutions and didn't work in my case, so I removed the git repo and added it again. Solved all issues.

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:org_name/project_name.git
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git fetch origin <branchName>:<branchName>

git checkout <branchName>
```

Make sure there are no new commits done after you have run first command
`git push --set-upstream origin <branchName>`

Answer (score 0):

I got this in Github desk top after clicking "Update from..." when the wrong repo was selected. I then changed repo to the correct one but when I tried to remove changes I got this error. That's because these were new files in the repo I errantly selected but not in the one I wanted to update from.

I simply changed the repo selector back to the one I incorrectly selected the first time then I was able to remove the changes.

Then I changed the repo selector to the one I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I tried to checkout using specific tag but the tag value was incorrect. Here's an example how easy it can be:

```
git@github.com:user/reponame?ref=1.0.0
```

this was incorrect and below is the correct one (note `v` before the version name):

```
git@github.com:user/reponame?ref=v1.0.0
```

If you're not familiar with all those tiny details it's really easy to omit them.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I did not have a `master` branch, it was called `main`.

There are many answers here suggesting individuals had typos or they were not sure of what the branch name actually is (or in the wrong repo), but none of the answers suggest how one can go about confirming this.

```
git branch
```

will populate a list of all of the branches one has (in the current repo), with the current branch highlighted in green (at least on git bash) and preceded by an asterisk.

If the branch you are trying to switch to *is* in this list (and the spelling matches), then try the other answers including `git fetch`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me as well on Windows on two local branches I created myself. 
Once out of the branch, I was not able to checkout

*bugfix_#303_multiline_opmerkingen_not_displaying_correctly_in_viewer*

nor

*bugfix_339_hidden_fields_still_validated*

you can see in the screenshot from Git bash below.

[image]

When I tried using Git GUI, I wasn't even able to see the branches at all. However when I used Pycharms git tool, I saw this:

[image]

So for some reason windows decided to add some indecipherable character to my branch names and that is the reason it didn't work. Renaming the branches in Pycharm did the trick, so guess this would work on other IDEs as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I solved my error!

First I deleted my repo locally and also from my Github. Then I forked and cloned to my local repository.

After that, I made my change to it and finally

Created My branch using

`$git checkout -b moh_branch`

change working branch

`$git checkout moh_branch`

push the branch to GitHub

`$git push origin moh_branch`

After that, I am able to commit my change as follow:-

`$git add .`

`$git commit -m "updated readme.md"`

`$git push origin moh_branch`

Succeeded 100% for me!!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem (with a version of git-recent) and discovered it was to do with color escape codes used by git.  I wonder whether this could explain why this problem is occurring so commonly.

This is demonstrates what could be happening, though color is normally set in git configuration rather than the command line (otherwise it's effect would be obvious):

```
~/dev/trunk (master)$ git checkout `git branch -l  --color=always  | grep django-1.11`
error: pathspec 'django-1.11' did not match any file(s) known to git.
~/dev/trunk (master)$ git branch -l  --color=always  | grep django-1.11
  django-1.11
~/dev/trunk (master)$ git checkout `git branch -l  | grep django-1.11`
Switched to branch 'django-1.11'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'gerrit/django-1.11'.
~/dev/trunk (django-1.11)$
```

I figure a git config that doesn't play with the color settings should work color=auto should do the right thing. My particular issue was because the `git recent` I was using was defined as an alias with hard coded colors, and I was trying to build commands on top of that

Answer (score -2):

Since your feature branch exists in remote, it's your local repo that's corrupted. So, delete your local repo and re-clone. Now '`git checkout <branch_name>`' should work for you.

Comment: Deleting the repo is bad advice.  The branch did not exist on the remote and he would have lost all his work on the branch.

Answer (score -3):

**My SPECIAL CASE** have the same error:

```
git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

**MY SPECIAL CASE AND MY SPECIAL CASE SOLUTION:** Since Git's "master" name updated with "main", new project can only use "main".

```
git checkout main
```

Please do not use when you don't have same case with me.

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me. It discards all local changes and resets it to the last commit.

```
git reset --hard
```

Answer (score -4):

If you're on Windows you just probably change filename to lower/upper case like File.txt - file.txt

So check what file you have in git and rename it to what you want:

```
git status
```

Then I need file.txt -> but git status gaves me File.txt so just rename it

```
git mv File.txt file.txt
```

And problem is solved.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be related to the question at all?

Comment: It could be an option if you change file names on Windows.