# What does the git error mean "pathspec did not match any file(s)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

In a Rails app I realised I had committed a sensitive file config/credentials.yml to the git repo.

In an effort to tidy things up I followed the [advice on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) and ran

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch config/credentials.yml' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

and then added to gitignore

```
echo "config/credentials.yml" >> .gitignore
```

When I try to commit these changes

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "ignored credentials.yml"
```

I'm getting a message

```
error: pathspec 'adds credentials.yml to gitignore' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How can I fix this error? Or, how can I undo my changes and safely revert to the git history on my remote?

Comment: Might this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn)

Answer (score 3):

I think you might've forgotten the step

```
$ git add .gitignore
```

before trying to commit, or then you mistyped, when you shoud've given

```
$ git commit -m "Add credentials.yml to .gitignore"
```

Process advised is highly dangerous [for the repo contents], so one must be really careful to follow all the steps in detail.

Comment: thanks eis. I had already run `git add .gitignore`. Are there any other steps i can take to resolve this? I realize this is a dangerous process, and am reluctant to take any more steps on my own without advice

Comment: grateful for your advice on this, if I use `git reset HEAD --hard` to reset local from my remote repo, will this undo these changes I've made to the local git. Or does the routine above run deeper than that! Apologies, still trying to get my head around this.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a file path while adding file to **git add** command, it works for me

$ git add mainFolder/.../file.extension

Note: mainFolder would be the folder inside your repo