# git shallow clone (clone --depth) misses remote branches

Tags: git, branch, shallow-clone

After cloning a remote repository it does not show any remote branch by -a option. What could be the problem? How to debug it? In this snippet two of the remote branches are not shown:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 git://git.savannah.gnu.org/pythonwebkit.git
$ cd pythonwebkit
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.1
```

Tried the same command on another machine, it works well:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 git://git.savannah.gnu.org/pythonwebkit.git
Receiving objects: 100% (186886/186886), 818.91 MiB | 3.44 MiB/s, done.
$ cd pythonwebkit/
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/debian
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/python_codegen
$ git --version
git version 1.7.1
```

Tried also cloning another repo, it works well. Though I can try it on this machine again, but it would be better to know what's wrong.

Any suggestions or hints will be more than welcome.

Edit: Answer summary: Since git version 1.8.3.2 the "--depth" and "--no-single-branch" need to be used together to get the same behavior as before. This is deemed a bug fix.

Comment: `master` is your local branch. `remotes/origin/master` is the corresponding remote branch. What exactly is the question?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the verbosity?  Try `git branch -avv`

Comment: To michas etc: we usually do not refer master as a branch, sorry for the confusion. added "two remote branches are not shown". To jthill: thanks for reminding, you are correct.

Comment: Thanks for introducing `git clone --depth=1 --no-single-branch`, this is what I need in most cases.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The behavior is correct, after the last revision the master-branch is (since this is the primary remote's HEAD) the only remote-branch in the repository:

```
florianb$ git branch -a
        * master
          remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
          remotes/origin/master
```

The full clone offers new (all) branches:

```
florianb$ git branch -a
        * master
          remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
          remotes/origin/debian
          remotes/origin/master
          remotes/origin/python_codegen
```

---

#### Shallow clones

Due to the [shallow-description](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a907786af835ac15962be53f1492f23e044f479/Documentation/technical/shallow.txt) in the technical documentation, a "`git-clone --depth 20 repo` [...] result[s in] commit chains with a length of at most 20." A shallow clone therefore should contain the requested depth of commits, from the tip of a branch.

As - in addition - the documentation of [`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6a907786af835ac15962be53f1492f23e044f479/Documentation/git-clone.txt) for the `--single-branch`-option describes:

> "Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the `--branch` option or the primary branch remote's `HEAD` points at. **When creating a shallow clone with the `--depth` option, this is the default, unless `--no-single-branch` is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches.**"

Therefore a shallow **clone** (**with** the **depth**-option) only **fetches** only **one single branch** (at your requested depth).

---

Unfortunately both options (`--depth` and `--single-branch`) have been faulty in the past and the use of shallow clones implicits unresolved problems (as you can read in the link I posted above), which is caused by the given history-rewrite. This leads in overall to somewhat complicated behavior in special cases.

Comment: florianb: what is your git version? thanks for trying it out. I did the --depth 1 on 1.7.1 just now it shows all the remote branches. updated the question with this. +1 for verifying the problem.

Comment: @minghua: I'm using 1.8.4 - i'll do a little investigation if there was a patch on that issue.

Comment: I'm confused. Is it a bug or not? My 1.8.3.1 behave the same as your 1.8.4, but different from 1.7. Which one is correct behavior? The release note means 1.8.3.1 should be different from 1.8.3.2 and later versions... IMHO shallow history should not cut current branches. Since I can check out shallow and still see all remote branches with 1.7.1, they are still there. The branches can be seen on the git web interface too. I don't think 1.8.4 is right... or I'm missing something?

Comment: @minghua: i edited to reflect new findings about "shallowed clones".

Comment: It's almost perfect except only one thing: what does it mean by saying "the repo-owner decided to cut the other branches off"? I think those branches are still there.

Comment: @minghua - you're absolutely right, i modified the answer.

Comment: --no-single-branch also clones all tags.  We can avoid that by creating a new repo, using the same config to fetch all remotes, i.e. `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, and running `git fetch --depth 1` (without `--tags`).  We can also add specific tags to be fetched, using config like `fetch = +refs/tags/v2.0.0:refs/tags/v2.0.0`.

Comment: I'm not happy with this answer as it doesn't touch upon the OPs implicit question: how to get all of the branches while not fetching the whole repo.

Comment: @user239558 - i am sorry, but i couldn't read any implicit question about fetching. I hope the OP flagged this answer as answer because it answered her question.

Answer (score 381):

After doing a shallow clone,
to be able to **checkout other branches from remote** do:

1. Run (thanks @jthill)  [doc about set-branches](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-branchesem):

   ```
   git remote set-branches origin '*'
   ```
2. After that, do a `git fetch -v --depth=1`
3. Finally `git checkout the-branch-i-ve-been-looking-for`

---

Step 1 can also be done manually by editing `.git/config`.

For instance, change the following line from:

```
fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

to (replace `master` with `*`):

```
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: You can also use `git remote set-branches origin '*'` for all branches, replace the `*` with a branchname for one.

Comment: What does `-vvv` mean in`git fetch -vvv`? I coundn't find any information about it in git-fetch  doc

Comment: @guo it is for the `verbosity` or `debug` logging level of `git`. It is not from `fetch` method.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of shallow cloning.

Comment: @kawing-chiu this is useful if you have so many branches and the size is to big for the 'internet connection' before and now could afford to get all those branches. :)

Comment: It worked fine for me, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: `git remote set-branches origin '*'` has a minor issue, `'*'` single quotes in the command surrounding asterisk causes an issue. The command changes the git config file to `fetch = +refs/heads/'*':refs/remotes/origin/'*'`, which causes an issue and does not fetch remaining branches in repository.

Comment: @KrutiParekh Hi. In my git config file, the command with single quotes generated `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` and it works fine. I'm using "git version 2.31.1.windows.1", what version are you using?

Comment: You can also use `git remote show origin` to see the remote branches that have been tracked.

Comment: For me step 2. was `git fetch -v --depth=1` to keep the amount of data I downloaded bearable.

Comment: This will make you download everything (which defeats the purpose of shallow cloning). See @alejandrodnm answer below.

Comment: @KrutiParekh using double quotes instead worked for me: `git remote set-branches origin "*"`

Comment: I'm on a slower network. So, I first downloaded the repo with `--depth 1`. Then in step 2, instead of `--depth=1` I used `git fetch --unshallow` that downloaded everything for every branch.

Comment: I played with this approach a little bit. I have a relatively large repository (a lot of branches with not so many content inside each). After a regular `git clone` the size of `.git` folder is 2.82GB. If I do just `clone --depth=1` it is 18MB. After the steps described in this answer the size becomes 121MB. So I would not say "it is pointless". I am going to use this approach to see how it works in practice.

Answer (score 118):

From reading the responses and the comment from @jthill, the thing that worked best for me was to use the `set-branches` option on the [`git remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/dogescript/dogescript.git
$ git remote set-branches origin 'remote_branch_name'
$ git fetch --depth 1 origin remote_branch_name
$ git checkout remote_branch_name
```

This changes the list of branches tracked by the named remote so that we can fetch and checkout just the required branch.

Comment: It might be better to use `git remote set-branches --add origin 'remote_branch_name'` so that the new branch is in addition to existing ones, rather than replacing them in the remote's list of branches (or branch patterns) to fetch in the .git/config file.

Comment: OMG, the single quote `'` is important in `git remote set-branches --add origin 'remote_branch_name'`

Comment: @Weekend I couldn't get this working until I left the single quotes out

Comment: @PandaWood You are probably on Windows. The "$" sign in the answer implies Bash (on Unix or Cygwin/MSYS).

Comment: I don't see anything about the single quotes being necessary in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) and it seems to work fine without one on macOS at least.