# Cancel "git fetch --unshallow"

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My question is quite simple but I can't find any solution.

I use `electron-react-boilerplate` for a project, so I cloned it using `---depth=1`.
Then, I was failing to push my changed to my own origin (a BitBucket repo), because I was developping on a shallow repo.

So I used `git fetch --unshallow upstream` (upstream being the boilerplate origin), however, as expected, it loaded all the commits from the boilerplate, which I don't want.

This makes the git tree dirty, is there a way to reverse the `git fetch --unshallow` command ? Reflog gives nothing.
Moreover, why did I need the unshallow in the first place, since I was already pushing on my own repo ?

Comment: Git has long-supported `git fetch --depth=...` as both *in*crease and *de*crease the depth of a clone: i.e., it now (but did not always) sets a fixed depth. It is, however, not clear to me just how that affects any commits *you* may have made (I see some ways it can be defined well and would hope Git uses those but this may be Git-version-dependent). There are still limitations on *pushing* from shallow clones, though: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6900103/1256452

Answer (score 1):

meet the same situation,
seems it's not easy directly.

shallow clone
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930421/4896468

fetch branches
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37593674/4896468

I use this way, clone a new shallow repo,

fetch braches one by one, with
`-depth NUM` or
`--single-brach --branch NAME`
on demand

---

### some cmds

#### clone

// one branch with 4 commit history

```
git clone --depth=4 --branch=mybranch  file:///run/test/linux linux_2
```

// one brach with all history (of this branch)

```
git fetch --single-branch --branch main file:///run/test/linux linux_3
```

#### fetch

cd linux_2

// one branch with 4 commit history

```
git remote set-branches origin 'branch1'
git fetch --depth 4 origin branch1
git checkout branch1
```

// one brach with all history (of this branch)

```
git remote set-branches origin 'branch2'
git fetch --single-branch origin branch2
git checkout branch2
```

Comment: I guess `filter-branch` maybe able to do such things, but I don't known how