# Access repo branches in Github Action

Tags: git, continuous-integration, git-branch, github-actions

I would like to perform a branch comparison in a Github Action. But `git branch` returns an `ls`-like result instead with a list of files!

`run: echo $(git branch)`

> shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
>
> LICENSE README.md index.html node_modules package-lock.json package.json src yarn.lock (HEAD detached at pull/29/merge)

Why is that? Is it broken?

How to perform git commands on branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git branch` returns a list in which the current branch is marked with an asterisk `*`. Then `echo` (actually, the shell) expands the asterisk.

Either process the output of `git branch` and remove `*` or use [`git for-each-ref refs/heads/`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).

*Upd*. `git clone --depth` [implies](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt) `--single-branch`. To fetch other branches:

```
git remote set-branches origin '*'
git fetch
```

See [git shallow clone (clone --depth) misses remote branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23708231/7976758)

Comment: Thanks! This answers why the list of files is added. But I still don't know why I can't see other branches. By the way, I can also add `fetch-depth: 0` to the checkout, as recommended by the docs, but it doesn't help.

Comment: "*I still don't know why I can't see other branches.*" Most probably because Github Action didn't fetch them. Please be advised that `git clone --depth` implies `--single-branch`.

Comment: Correct. I'll validate the answer, if you could add the `git fetch` to the run