# Not able to checkout remote branch, git branch -a also does not show remote branches

Tags: git

I am trying to checkout remote branch, but it fails with

```
error: pathspec 'branchName' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Git branch -a shows only the local branches and master branch but not other remote branches.

I think this is config problem but not able to sort out. Help!

Edit 1:

```
git remote show origin
```

fails with

```
fatal: Invalid refspec '....'
```

Can anyone provide a standard content for this in .git/config file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: cannot checkout branch - error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT isn't fetching my new branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663933/git-isnt-fetching-my-new-branch)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I had guessed, the problem was with the config. Git Fetch was not helping.

My config had the remote origin content as

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/
    url = "git repo url"
```

But it is important to append * next to the origin/ and heads/

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = "git repo url"
```

Comment: Good you found the problem. I'm curious about what caused this configuration problem...

Comment: I am not sure too... May be this was unintended change that got in while I was making other config changes months back.

Comment: thank you! just spent the past half hour trying to find out what the problem was until I finally stumbled onto this!

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look here: [Git: cannot checkout branch - error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn)

Probably you need to "git fetch" before checkout (your local repository seems to not know about the remote).