# GIT isn't fetching my new branch

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch

I have created a new branch on my remote, so I would expect to do this:

```
$ git fetch && git checkout feature/name
```

However, I get this error:

```
error: pathspec 'feature/name' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

When I run `git fetch` on its own, it doesn't return anything, I have also tried `git fetch origin` which does not work either.

`git remote` returns just the one remote called `origin`.

My config looks like this:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = removed as it is a private repo
    fetch = +refs/heads/staging:refs/remotes/origin/staging
[branch "staging"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/staging
```

Comment: you could use `git pull`

Comment: But my branch doesn't exist yet. And I haven't created the branch in my local repo and potentially wouldn't have the original branch the the remote branch has branched from.

Comment: Your origin.fetch line is not the git default.  Normal is `remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: @AndrewC: that's the reason for the problem; you should add it as an answer.

Comment: @torek - That requires more work :)  And this one smelled like a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The fix is to correct your `remote.origin.fetch` parameter, e.g.

```
git config remote.origin.fetch '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*'
```

so all branches can be fetched. See: [How to fetch all remote branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957760/55075)

Answer (score 1):

As per Andrew C's comment. I changed the `fetch` line in my git config to this:

```
fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on GIt >1.9.X you have a default upstream with the value of `simple`.

If you want to get all the branches and tags you should use: **`git fetch --all --prune`**
`--all` will fetch all the branches and tags
`--prune` will delete all the deleted branches and tags

The flags will apply on your local repository.