# VS Code / Bitbucket / SSH - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, windows-10, bitbucket

I'm trying to access bitbucket via ssh from vscode but always get *permission denied (publickey)*.

SSH key(s) are located under `~\.ssh\`, public key(s) are correctly setup in `bitbucket/settings/security/sshkeys`. The keys are tested and do work!

After booting, I can access my repository without problems from the windows command prompt and powershell but NOT from git bash or from vscode. Manually setting up ssh in git bash and starting vscode works though:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add /c/Users/username/.ssh/privatekey
code
```

**My environment:**

- Windows 10 Enterprise (1803/17134.765)
- Visual Studio Code (1.35.0)
- git for windows (2.20.1.windows.1)
- bitbucket via ssh
- *I think* I'm using the ssh-agent that was introduced in one of the later Windows10 updates (not sure how to check, the windows ssh-agent service is running though).
- my user folder (containing /.ssh) and the working copy of the repo are located on network drives

*For me the problem boils down to one question:
Why is vscode not using windows native, correctly setup ssh service and instead relying on git bash ssh agent?*

Disclaimer: I spent hours reading threads about this topic and fiddling with settings. I suspect the problem to be related to the delayed deployment of network drives under Windows10 (a known issue). My windows group policy is set to wait for the network on boot/login.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Windows 10 allows using all default OpenSSH tools. However, git was throwing permission denied for every time when I tried to clone repositories from Github, Gitlab or Bitbucket over SSH. You need to perform a few tweaks to make it work.

1. Make sure ssh-agent service enabled, or run in Powershell (as administrator):

`Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual`

2. `ssh-agent`
3. `ssh-add`
4. `git config --global core.sshCommand C:/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh.exe`

Comment: After the first command i get the following error: PS C:\Users\Tim> Get-Service -Name ssh-agent | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
Set-Service : Service 'OpenSSH Authentication Agent (ssh-agent)' cannot be configured due to the following error:
Access is denied

Comment: You will need to run Windows Powershell as an administrator (right-click 'Run as Administrator'). Otherwise you'll get Access is Denied errors.

Comment: @PasanJayawickrama Maybe you want `Set-Service -StartupType Automatic` instead.

Comment: can anyone tell me the linux equivalent? Wolud it simply be `git config --global core.sshCommand /usr/bin/ssh`? I tried it and it doesn't seem to solve the problem for VS Code on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Well, shoot. Those steps broke my setup, which worked fine before, with turtoise-git + pageant + ppk key. How do I revert those commands?

Comment: Update: I followed https://interworks.com/blog/2021/09/15/setting-up-ssh-agent-in-windows-for-passwordless-git-authentication/ which worked fine

Comment: as the 3rd command run not just `ssh-add` but `ssh-add <path-to-private-key-in-ssh-folder>`

Answer (score 12):

In case someone is looking for an answer in mac

`ssh-agent`

`ssh-add`,
after this command add your passphrase

Answer (score 7):

I've had this for sooo long, and finally got to the bottom of it!

Note, I'm on Windows 10.

There are quite a few things that can be wrong. Some of those are fixed in the other answers.
Also over time and various VSCode versions (or VS or GitHub Desktop or other programs using git), it has been different. An update to OpenSSL (which is automatic) was also the culprit once.
In short, it's a mess to figure out what's going on.

I've got two more points to add that you could debug to figure out what's going on:

1. related to `PATH`
2. related to `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`

### PATH

What we need to verify is that the `git.exe` used by your IDE is the same one you talk to on the terminal.

Whenever you're in Git Bash for Windows ("Bash" from now on), the `PATH` is different from the global `PATH`, as Bash inserts some paths, in my case

- `/mingw64/bin`
- `/usr/bin`
- `$HOME/bin`
  (note that the paths starting with `/` are automatically prepended with the git installation folder, which by default is `C:\Program Files\Git`).

This can cause Bash and the IDE to resolve different `git.exe`, as `PATH` is used for that (and `ssh.exe` and `ssh-add.exe`).
When I start my IDE, vscode in my case, it uses Windows' PATH to resolve `git.exe` and it found (in my setup) `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe`. That's really unfortunate, because in the Bash terminal it finds `/mingw64/bin/git.exe`.
You can find VSCode's git version from the very first line in the Git log in the Output panel. The bash one simply by running `which git` or `where git` (the latter will show you all of them on `PATH`).

I standardized on using the git in `mingw64` by adapting the `PATH` accordingly.

Now if you have your `ssh-agent` enabled, you enter your passphrase in the terminal you might expect that from then on your IDE can resolve the passphrase too, as they use the same `git.exe` and thereby the same `ssh.exe` and `ssh-add.exe`.

### SSH_AUTH_SOCK

The only thing that's truly important for any terminal or IDE to communicate with the `ssh-agent` is that it knows about it. That's solely conferred by the environment variable `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` (see the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/search?q=ssh_get_authentication_socket)).
If your IDE or terminal doesn't know about this environment variable, it's not going to find the passphrase in the `ssh-agent`.

It's important to realize how this environment variable is communicated among various programs.
This is why many answers on SO will write it to a file `~/.ssh/agent.env` and will read that on every bash terminal. But this has no effect on IDEs.
This also is not a great solution if you combine it with Powershell:

- which also doesn't write that `.env` file so bash wouldn't know about the ssh-agent

  - That's why `-StartupType Automatic` has no affect in the terminal
  - If you see multiple ssh-agents being spawn, this could be the reason.
- Nor does Powershell read from the `.env` file, so it doesn't know about the bash-instantiated `ssh-agent`

You could confirm that this is in fact the issue by starting your IDE with the environment variable set, for instance by contrasting

- `code ./your-project` (which gives permission-denied) with
- `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-...your/agent...; code ./your-project`
  (which doesn't give permission denied, assuming `ssh-client` is up
  and populated, i.e. `ssh-add` has been called elsewhere).

You can find the socket of your agent by running `ssh-agent`, it'll print it (otherwise you haven't started it or added your passphrase yet). I'm just concluding along the way that `ssh-agent` is a binary that prints an executable bash, hence you can do `` eval `ssh-agent` `` .

Now the question is how you can get your VSCode to know about `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`. There are some ways listed above (and e.g. [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting#_setting-up-the-ssh-agent)), and those have worked for me sometimes, but not always/currently.
I also don't see how that would work. Let me know if you do.

If you start vscode from the terminal which exports `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, then it'll have access to the `ssh-agent`, but if you start vscode from the start menu or another shortcut, yeah,
then it's not going to have the environment variable. You can't really make it a global environment variable in the System Environment at system startup because the value is assigned too late: only when running the ssh-agent.

So currently I do just that. I restart vscode from the vscode terminal. That's not really satisfactory. I'm considering changing the shortcut. One last question I have, to anyone who come so far: how *is* an IDE supposed to know about the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable? I don't see it. VSCode doesn't seem to run `~./bashrc` on startup, only for the terminals. Maybe this is behavior that varies over the VSCode versions?

### Miscellaneous

Last things you could just: make sure your environment variables `GIT_SSH` and `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` are empty (that you haven't played with them, and forgotten about that).
Same goes for the git config `sshCommand`. (I have mine pointed to `C:/Program\\ Files/Git/usr/bin/ssh.exe`).

Comment: I love this solution, however for people who don't want to change their $PATH for 'reasons' - you can set the git.path value in vscode instead. The path is likely to be something like `"git.path": "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git.exe"`

Comment: This answer helped me but I'm not sure if the symptoms was exactly the same. I ended up starting VSCode from a terminal that I had run ssh-agent and ssh-add and entered my passkey.
I previously had this issue and it was resolved by running ssh-add on the terminal inside VSCode but it didn't work* this time.
*it half worked, inside the terminal I can do push/pull to sync, but if I click the  'sync' button on the VSCode Source Control sidebar menu it gave the error.
It appears that VSCode has a config or env that is seperate to the terminals but I don't know how to control/refresh that.

Comment: @DouglasYoung: Your behavior is expected, as per my explanation. To get e.g. the 'sync' button to work as well, try to start VSCode from a terminal (that has the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` env var). Use the VSCode terminal if need be, but the close the first VSCode instance. Basically the explanation is that the env vars known to VSCode's terminal are a different environment than those knows to VSCode itself (also the latter populates the first). Good luck.

Comment: @JBSnorro yep, that's exactly my thoughts. I just don't know why I didn't have this problem before. I'm pretty sure(and I could be remembering incorrectly haha) the 'sync' button worked after I did the ssh-add on the VSCode terminal, which led me to think that VSCode app and the terminal were tied, which doesn't seem to be the case based on my current experience

Comment: @DouglasYoung Yes, I've seen the same. Like I said: "Maybe this is behavior that varies over the VSCode versions"

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the answer from Alexandr Pilgun some additional information that made the difference for me.

At step 4 I needed to provide double backslashes. VSCode complained that it could not find the ssh.exe. Using the double backslashes looks like this:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe
```

I am using Windows 10.0.19042 Enterprise

Comment: Tried this solution as well, I know have ````Cloning into 'C:\Users\yamab\Source\Repos\prdb-intro'...
C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\ssh.exe: C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: No such file or directory
Error encountered while cloning the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.´´´´ when trying to clone the repo

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, I have to launch VS Code from bash.

```
> code
```

Then it inherits what I've got in .bashrc to load ssh agent with the keys I use. Slight inconvenience, but I usually have bash open as well if I'm working in VS Code anyway.

This is what JBSnorro has described in much more detail above.

Bottom of this page kind of recommends this approach:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/versioncontrol

Comment: That is the solution when using Git for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was resolved for me by using Windows Secure Channel library for HTTPS connections.

[image]