# Visual Studio Code Remote Edit git authentication issue

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I've been pulling my hair out with this for a while now.

Running Visual Studio Code (1.65.2) on Windows 10.

So I have a remote SSH connection to a linux machine, on which I have directory, which is a git repository and is synced to Github.

Whenever I try to use the Visual Studio Codes' sync button, I get the following error.

```
[2022-03-19T17:29:29.276Z] > git pull --tags origin new-time-management [787ms]
[2022-03-19T17:29:29.276Z] git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

From the Output of VSC, I can see that it seems to be using the git on the Remote host, since this is the git version the Remote host runs, but my local machine uses a newer one:

```
[2022-03-19T17:46:55.585Z] Validating found git in: git
[2022-03-19T17:46:55.624Z] Using git 2.25.1 from git
```

Which is kind of confusing, since all guidance I've read so far seems to hint that I should be changing my ~/.ssh/config & referring to keys on my local machine. Anyways, I configured everything correctly there just in case, but does not seem to help.

My ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host github.com
  User git
  Hostname github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github_private_key.ppk
  AddKeysToAgent yes
```

When I use the terminal from VSC, all git authentications work fine, since it's probably basically just an ssh connection to the remote host.

Also all the local (inside remote-ssh) git functionality works fine.

I tried using all the guides I found, but none worked so far. For example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634364/to-use-git-push-on-visual-studio-code-but-show-could-not-read-from-remote-re) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56490194/vs-code-bitbucket-ssh-permission-denied-publickey).

I'm probably missing some fundamental understanding of how this is supposed to work. Is it supposed to run the git on the remote host or local, when using Remote-SSH?

Comment: Not an answer to your particular question, but note that if you use command-line Git, it runs an ssh on *both sides* (well, technically it runs ssh on your side, which invokes an sshd on the remote to speak ssh protocol) and then there's also Git software on *both sides*.  How much of this VSRemote eliminates (by absorbing some local-side jobs into itself), I don't know; VonC's answer suggests "most or all of it".

Answer (score 0):

> Is it supposed to run the git on the remote host or local, when using Remote-SSH?

On the remote host, where the push/pull is supposed to happen.

That means you should open an interactive ssh session (outside of VSCode) to that server, and check a [`ssh -Tv github.com` works](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) (meaning: "ends with a 'Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.'")

The idea is to check/debug from command line (on the remote host) first: once that is working, chances are the VSCode Remote SSH session will benefit from the same working commands.

Comment: As I stated in my first post: "When I use the terminal from VSC, all git authentications work fine"

Comment: ssh -T github.com:
"You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access." from VSC terminal.

Comment: @SalaDus The terminal from VSC is local, not on the remote server. That is why I requested to test from an interractive session opened on the remote server, outside of VSCode, to see if github.com does authenticate you properly there.

Comment: It's definitely not local for a SSH connection. Anyways, either way the ssh test works from VSC terminal and a separate SSH session to the server. https://imgur.com/a/j6umAlj