# Visual studio Code - prevent same file opening twice

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

It's happened a few times before that I've opened the same file twice and forgotten about it. Meaning I was editing the same file in both panes, which means two versions of the same file. This led to bugs and me not understanding why me code was not being run properly.

Is there a setting which prevents having the same file open twice?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

### Update v1.11.0 - March 2017

I [submitted this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/21815), and you can now use the setting:

```json
"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true
```

In the Settings GUI search for: **Workbench > Editor: Reveal If Open**

Comment: Is there a way to add this command to my settings/script/workbench startup? Curious because it's a year ago this was added, but it's causing me confusion for some reason still.

Comment: @ConradB Am not sure what you mean by "add this command" - this is just a setting which is either on ("true") or off ("false"). You can add it to your settings either using the new UI for settings or pure JSON, in which case if you copy the settings name from my above comment you will get intellisense and help.

Comment: Is there a setting to get this to work across instances? I use multiple monitors, and would love to have one instance per display and have them know more about each other to bring files opened in one instance to the front when "opened" from another instance.

Comment: @AberrantWolf I am not sure that I understand the scenario. If the windows open on different monitors are all showing the same "workspace" - whether this is a named workspace or an implicitly created one by opening a folder - I have difficulties imagining how this could be useful. In general, I am not aware of _any_ feature in VSCode which works across Windows/workspaces. Could you please clarify your scenario? Alternatively, if your use case makes sense for you and VSCode team, excellent opportunity to contribute the feature? My experience with the team was nothing but pleasant, do recommend!

Comment: @rawpower When editing (C++ mostly), I prefer to have many file laid out and never hide any behind tabs -- tabbing loses context, and when dealing with complicated systems, it's really frustrating. So in traditional Visual Studio, I have one "window" per monitor (I use 3), and 2 columns per window, which is sometimes enough to never need tabs. I'd like to do this same thing with VSCode. But it's too easy to to accidentally try to open a file in Window B that's already open in Window A; I would prefer if it just brought Window A's buffer to the front instead.

Comment: @AberrantWolf I now understand what you mean. The issue is that in VSCode you cannot - to my knowledge - have 2 or more windows using the same logical workspace. In Visual Studio you are literally "tearing out editors" and creating new OS Windows. In VSCode, unless I missed something, you can open multiple VS Code windows but then in each of the windows you need to open another copy of the workspace. Therefore, the setting I've added doesn't work because it applies to a single workspace. I _think_ they are planning to allow for pulling editors out, but am not sure.

Comment: where are we supposed to put this in?

Comment: @ahnbizcad if you want to copy and paste, then go to settings, then switch to “raw” representation (which is just JSON). Otherwise just search for the part of the name in the UI (the only input box at the top).

Comment: @ahnbizcad so, open settings (Cmd/Ctrl+,), then click leftmost icon in the upper right corner (tooltip says "Open Settings (JSON)", the settings UI disappears and JSON appears. Insert above immediately after the opening brace `{` and don't forget to add comma. If you don't know what JSON is and/or are afraid to break something, just use the UI: when settings UI opens, type "reveal" in the search box (already focused when UI opens), the second setting is "Workbench>Editor: Reveal If Open" (with a long explanation of the above), simply check the checkbox.

Comment: @rawpower I see. you can also search the exact `workbench.editor.revealIfOpen` and it finds it even in the UI too.

Comment: This only works if `"window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off"`. i.e. you are opening the already opened file in the same window. If vscode is default to opening files in a new window, then the `revealIfOpen` option doesn't work at all.

Comment: @rawpower thanks man! I was wondering if it makes sense to move the open file to the current editor group? Perhaps `moveIfOpen`? The rationale is that, I lose track visually when the reveal is in another group, either move or some visual cue indicating it's in another group

Comment: @bilogic That's... actually useful, IMO. A good opportunity for a first PR to VSCode? ;)

Comment: @rawpower haha, let's not get ahead of myself, while I enjoy coding a feature, I'm unfamiliar with tooling required to compile VSCode.. do you know if there is a dummy guide to compiling it? Meanwhile, what I did was to make the focused tab as bright as the title bar.. works around the problem for now

Answer (score 3):

It looks like under Edit-Preferences there is a checkbox for the setting, Workbench - Editor: Reveal If Open: [image]

Comment: the accepted answer by rawpower says the same, what is the point of copy/pasting that

Comment: the point is, it lets you actually find it, as opposed to the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Just update VS Code and if still doesn't work after update reinstall it. It happened to me and reinstalling solved my problem.

Comment: yeah, doesn't work for me.  It used to work, but one day I noticed the same file open in multiple groups.  Then paying attention, it totally just opens a new tab when even though the file is already open.  Maybe I need to try the reinstall.  (I'm on 1.84.2, the latest as of this post)

Answer (score 0):

Afaiak this has now been fixed in the latest updates of the application, as when editing one file, the other files also updates now.

Comment: While it's cool that both instances edit, I'd also like to know - is there a setting which prevents one file to be open in more than one editor?

Comment: @rawpower Not that I'm aware of, you'll have to check the docs :)

Comment: I'm currently working on a fix ;) (so no, there is no option for this)