# Open already opened file in a different editor group in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

What I am looking for is a way to do the following in Visual Studio Code:

- Go to Definition on a symbol (which often opens a new file in the same editor group)
- **Open this newly opened file in a editor group next to current**
- ... and switch back to the original file

Is there a command / key binding that would let me do 2nd bullet item?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am on Windows 10

Comment: related: [Visual studio Code - prevent same file opening twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39890926/11107541)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Short Answer

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> does that on Windows.

#### Details

This is my normal flow:

1. <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to a symbol definition.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> to open the file on the right.

#### On Linux or iOS

Find the equivalent shortcut by opening File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (or running `Open Keyboard Shortcuts` in the command palette), and searching for these two commands:

- `workbench.action.moveEditorToNextGroup`
- `workbench.action.moveEditorToPreviousGroup`

Comment: Thanks a lot! And just for the sake of completeness, do you know to clone (not moving, but open another instance of that file instead) to the other group?

Comment: @JimRaynor Not off the top of my head... if you find one let me know.

Comment: `Window.MovetoPreviousTabGroup` and 'Window.MovetoNextTabGroup` in windows if you want to change the shortcut keys for moving. For cloning, I couldn't find a good one yet. (I miss Android Studio. Xcode was still good enough)

Answer (score 3):

If you are here, like me, looking for a way to open files in the next group, by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>.

Then adding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to the combination may do the trick. My VSCode version is `1.60`.

!IMPORTANT: The new tab opened via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, will always be to the right of the current. So, if you have already opened two groups, then move the tab to the left to have new tabs at the right, otherwise it will create third group.

Comment: I tried that from search result, but it open 2 editors to the right. I'm using `1.81.1` but can't fight the mapping in the keyboard setting searching for `ctrl+alt+click` or `ctrl+alt+down`

Answer (score 1):

- in mac os you can use this key binding <kbd>cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>\</kbd>
- in windows you can use this key binding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is a combination of the answers above.  I find this works:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> *View: Split Editor*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> *View: Move Editor into Next Group*

**Equivalently**

- (no default keybinding) *View: Split Editor into Right Group*

**Caveat:** if the file is already open in the other editor group, then it will be opened (not "cloned").  There may be a configuration setting to alter this behavior, but I couldn't find one quickly.

The result looks as follows.  Suppose you are in some file on the left, and there is another editor group on the right (e.g. after executing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>).  After running the two commands above, then the currently open file will still be open on the left, but will also be open in the editor group on the right.

**Tip:** if you don't feel like assigning a keybinding, but would like to access the command (relatively) quickly, just type

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> `srg`