# Configure VS Code to jump to or go to file in open tab when clicked in Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to configure VS Code for the following behavior:

- Jump to an already open tab when file is clicked in the Explorer (left hand side bar)

Consider the situation:

- Multiple files are opened in VS Code, therefore there are multiple tabs open
- You have probably dragged the tab title bars around to configure your editing window
- You might have arranged several groups of tabs across several "panes"
- For example, you might have a two-pane vertical layout with 10 tabs open in the left pane and 12 tabs open in the right pane
- With so many tabs open, you probably can't see all the filenames at once (there isn't enough space to display them)
- You click a file in the Explorer, for a file which you know is already open somewhere on your screen.
- Rather than that "jumping" you to the already opened tab, it creates a new tab

Here's a screenshot to demonstrate:

[image: VS Code]

I hope the question is clear, and that the annotations at least somewhat helped to explain.

Basically, I have already opened `file5`, it just isn't visible in the scrolling list of tabs on the left window pane. If I make the right window pane active, by clicking it, and then I try to open `file5` from the Explorer, a new tab will be opened in the right window pane, rather than VS Code jumping to the already opened tab in the left pane.

[image: VS Code]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135102/836330.  Set the `Editor: Reveal If Open` setting to enabled.

Comment: loosely related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/49026

Answer (score 0):

Use the **OPEN EDITORS** view.

If you can't see it use the `...` menu in the **EXPLORER** title bar.

If you click in the Explorer tree and the file is not open in the current tab group VSC will open the file **again** in the current tab group.

If you need the whole bar for the File Explorer you can move/drag the OPEN EDITORS view to the other side bar.

You can collapse a view by clicking on the View Title Bar. This way you can switch quickly between the OPEN EDITORS and File view if they need a lot of space.

---

With the setting: **Editor: Reveal If Open** (Commented by Mark)

Use `Ctrl+P` and type part of the file name you are looking for.

If the file is already open somewhere it will be put to front, if not it will be opened in the current tab group.

---

Or use `Ctrl+TAB` and it will show the most recently used files first.

It only shows the files used in the current tab group.

Use the arrow keys and navigate to the file you want.

Comment: The issue with having both open at the same time is there is less real-estate for the Explorer view. With larger projects it's relatively easy to fill a whole 1440p screen height with a folder tree. But yes, this is a possible solution