# How to use <git push/sync> on Visual Studio Code, without admin rights?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code Push/Sync to Git. I've created SSH Key and added it to my GITHUB account. When I try to push, I keep getting this error notification:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I've tried it from my *private* computer, and had there no problems at all. But from my *work* computer- where I have **no admin rights**, it just won't work.

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634364/to-use-git-push-on-visual-studio-code-but-show-could-not-read-from-remote-re), but still no help.

Have anyone any idea how can I make it work?

Comment: Have you created a key-pair on **each** computer, and registered **each** pair's public key with GitHub?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes. Each computer has it's own key. I must add that if I push from terminal it works. Only the VSCode Sync/Push option won't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. make sure you used "`git clone`“ with the SSH Url and not HTTPS Url
2. just to make sure, you can copy again your public key with this command to you Remote Repository
   „`pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`“
3. Check your git config username und email with your Remote Git Provider (e. g. Beanstalk, Github etc.)
   „`git config user.email`“ und „`git config user.name`“
   and correct if necessary.
   „`git config user.email <YourEmail>`“
   „`git config user.name <YourUsername>`“
4. Add Identity Using Keychain
   “`ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa`”
   Just type in your password one more time after this.

You can see the change now in your ~/.ssh/id_rsa (if you want).

Should work after this.

Comment: Thanks @efebirol . Turned out that since I have no admin, I've also had to manualy add 'git\bin' path in my environment variables...