# Visual Studio Code: Push to git works from Terminal but not when using the user interface

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

Running Windows 8.1 64-bit with the following installed:

- Git for Bash (v2.24.1.windows.2) using MinGW-W64
- Visual Studio Code (v1.41.1)

My personal SSH key (located at `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`) has been generated and added to my GitHub account. `.bashrc` located at `%USERPROFILE` has been modified to add these lines:

```
# Start ssh-agent to allow git to be used
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_personal
```

I start Git Bash (MINGW64) in a git repo. Now make changes to a file, `git add`, `git commit` and `git push` the changes to my git repo...and it works fine!

For the standard Windows command prompt, I've created a file called `bashrc.cmd` with this code:

```
rem Start ssh-agent to use git from the Windows command line
set GIT_PATH=C:\Program Files\Git
call "%GIT_PATH%\cmd\start-ssh-agent.cmd"
call "%GIT_PATH%\usr\bin\ssh-add.exe" "%USERPROFILE%\.ssh\id_rsa_personal"
```

Now, a new `REG_SZ` value called `AutoRun` in the key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` was created which points to the above file (`bashrc.cmd`)

Start a command prompt, and now `ssh-agent` is started and my identity is added. As with Git Bash, `add`, `commit` and `push` work perfectly. Awesome!

Now I load Visual Studio Code in my git repo. In the lower left, Code knows I'm inside a git repo:

[image: master branch of my repo]

Using the in-built Terminal in Code, I can `add`, `commit` and `push` changes to my git repo. Great!

But now I try it with the user interface buttons. I can stage and commit changes and confirm in a separate command line windows using `git status` that these work as expected. But when I use the `Push` command, I get this error:

[image: Permission denied to git repo]

Return to the Code Terminal, or a Windows command prompt, or Git Bash, issue the command `git push` and the changes are sent to the remote repo correctly.

Why is this not working with the Code `Push` command?

Comment: I am also using git scm and integrated terminal, I have never tried with icons, but after reading this question, I have tried with my project and I have not faced any difficulties its working good, I have ssh key added in git that's it no more efforts.

Comment: Yes, very strange. For now, I use the icons to `Stage` and then `Commit` the changes. Then return to the in-built Terminal and issue the final `git push` command. Why the `Push` command via the user interface is failing remains a mystery.

Comment: @PrateikDarji: Turns out the problem was with the *name* of my SSH key. Even though I explicitly add my personal SSH key, VS Code appears to prefer the default name of `id_rsa`. Probably a Code bug or limitation. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some efforts I found same error in my Visual Studio Code, even when I tried to use `ctrl+shift+p` and `git:pull` command also gives me the same error as describe `Permission Denied(publickey)`

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634364/to-use-git-push-on-visual-studio-code-but-show-could-not-read-from-remote-re), that `Seems VS Code uses 'id_rsa.pub' key only`, and I'm having different name for the key pairs, then I copies private key and public key which was set for the git repository to id_rsa and id_rsa.pub and again I tried to check with icons as well as from menu and it works without adding into `ssh-agent` because it only search for ~/.ssh/id_rsa at your profile directory. When I deleted id_rsa it gives me the same error and terminal is working as expected with the different key name which is already added in ssh-agent.

Also the thing is, `git add .` and `git commit -m` are the commands which works for local not establish connection with remote branch but when you tries to `fetch`, `pull`, `push` tries to connect to remote repository where authentication is required.

Comment: That could be it! My keys also do not use the default names. Will try later and confirm.

Comment: Thanks! The name of the SSH key was the problem. I had a work-related SSH key called `id_rsa` (with the associated `id_rsa.pub` public key). My personal SSH key was called `id_rsa_personal`. When I (temporarily) renamed the work-related SSH key, then renamed my personal key to `id_rsa`...Visual Studio Code started working. Moreover, I no longer needed to manually start the `ssh-agent`.

This feels like a bug in Visual Studio Code.

I'll modify the question to include this detail.

Answer (score 1):

The problem also occurs when the key is protected by a passphrase. Regenerating another key without a passphrase solved my problem.

Comment: This is a workarount, but I don't think lowering security is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to push the changes using iterm on my mac bit not via vs code.
So as one of the above user suggested a key without a passphrase might work.
I tried it and it did work. I did not have to generate a new key.
I used this to update the passphrase.
ssh-keygen -p -f /path/to/ssh_key

your `ssh key` is the one without the `.pub` extension.

Answer (score 0):

After switching my Github account and generate a new SSH key. I was able to git pull from Terminal. But VSCode and IntelliJ could not. It seems to be using my previous credential.

Running `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` in both terminal did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

The name of RSA key is the exact reason why it happens. Required key file name has to be `~/.ssh/id_rsa` on remote host.
Just check it on the latest version.

- VSCode:1.61.0
- Remote-SSH: 0.65.8