# How to fix git hub permission denied on vscode

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

when i use vscode UI to push this dialog appears.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (public key)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository
```

I have setup SSH and signed into vscode, and all works on VScode terminal , git bash , and cmd. But im unable to use vscode UI functionalities.

`

Comment: try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634364/to-use-git-push-on-visual-studio-code-but-show-could-not-read-from-remote-re

Comment: it worked thank you