# VSCode using Git authentication

Tags: git, authentication, visual-studio-code

I'm using Git via VSCode but the issue is that

- every time I try to push my changes to my remote repository i'm supposed to put in my authentication credentials but using Git via VSCode it is not popping up the login screen. If i use Git on its own i do get the popup to type in my login credentials.

How can get Git within VSCode to popup the login form or somehow store my credentials in VScode so that automatically logs me into my remote repository and push my changes?

thank you

Comment: Are you using the SSH or HTTPS protocol to communicate with the remote repository?

Comment: I'm using ssh with private/public key authentication

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61596532/836330 for info on vscode v1.45 automatic git authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the credentials on your local disk using

> git config --global credential.helper 'store'

and push to your remote repo. **git** will ask you for your credentials and then stores them locally.

Another options is to use ssh authentication and use a ssh: remote uri.

Comment: Will this work with private/public key authentication via ssh? Thats how I authenticate

Comment: Hi Fmora, I gave it a try with one of mine git projects that I cloned and it works fine with SSH. I used the VS GUI to merge a small change and it worked fine. Did not ask me for a user password at all but pushed the changes to github.com.