# why error connecting to github from powershell command line?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

first time using GitHub.
Created the repository on github.com.  Now I want to push to that repository.  Getting "connection failed" error.

When I run "`ssh -Tv git@github.com`" I get "`connection timed out`".
And "`ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com`" fails with: `Permission denied`.

I turned off the windows firewall.  Same error.

What to do?  How to connect to GitHub?
I am using VSCode.  Working from the powershell command line.

Here are the commands I tried:

```
    PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh -Tv git@github.com
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.112] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.255.112 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.255.113] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.30.255.113 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> git push -u origin master
ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
The authenticity of host '[ssh.github.com]:443 ([192.30.253.123]:443)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[ssh.github.com]:443,[192.30.253.123]:443' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[192.30.253.122]:443' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-W7z0JBkeNSBz/agent.14164; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=14148; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 14148;

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh-add -l -E md5
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

PS C:\gitsteve\maker> ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: some more info. the git push -u origin master command worked from the git shell of the github desktop app.

Answer (score 1):

If SSH is blocked for any reason, try and switch to an https URL

```
 cd /path/to/repo
 git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git
```

Then try again

```
 git push -u origin master
```

Then first time, it should require your GitHub username/password (which has nothing to do with the passphrase you might have set on your private SSH key: it needs your GitHub account password)

If you have installed a [Git credential helper (as in this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36345679/6309), those GitHub credentials will be cached (meaning vscode won't ask you again for username/password at the next push)
Check first the value of `git config credential.helper`: if you see `manager`, you have nothing to do.