# vscode not showing git password prompt

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a git repo on a remote server and use ssh with password authentication to clone,pull,push. From command line everything works fine.

However in vscode when I try to pull or push from remote repository, no password prompt is shown. Vscode seems to be waiting for something but nothing happens.
Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I want to use visual studio code as git client on linux.

From command line:

[image]

In vscode:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two solutions I can think of:

- Set up an SSH key so that you never need credentials for accessing the server the remote repository is on
- Tell git to remember credentials when you type them in - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627954/1996926) tells you how

EDIT:

Here is a quick recipe how to set up an SSH key for your git repo:

**On the client side** (where you cloned the repository)

- Check if you have an ssh key in `~/.ssh`
- If not, generate an SSH key without passphrase using `ssh-keygen` (mine is called `id_rsa`)
- add this key to the authentication agent using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

**On the remote side** (where the repo is hosted)

- create the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- into this file copy and past your public key, which you just created on the client side (mine is saved in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

Afterwards try a `git pull` on the client side. It should not ask for a password anymore and pull/push from vscode should work as well

Comment: So I guess plain password authentication is just not supported by vscode then. Feels like a basic feature missing

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame. This seems like it would be a relatively common problem, though, so I'm surprised it isn't included...

Answer (score 1):

It's strange but, this is also caused if your VSCode has the GitlabFlow extension enabled. When uninstalled, the credentials prompt came back again.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode (1.25) does show password input prompt on Git `https` `clone` (if required) or `push`.

That is the feature is available. Not sure if your problem is `ssh` related, in which case it may be a bug, you may log on the VSCode issue-tracker.

Comment: The lack of SSH passphrase support has been raised as VS Code issue [#13680](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13680).