# VS Code git pull only works when Visual Studio (2017) is running

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, atlassian-sourcetree

Bizarre issue: Visual Studio Code and SourceTree are unable to push/pull/whatever *unless* Visual Studio (2017 in this case) is open and at least one Git operation has been performed. The error is `fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://central.com/repository.git/`. I guess it somehow inspires the others to work?

**How does Visual Studio 2017 handle Git operations such that it makes Git operations for other programs work too?**

I don't restart VS Code or SourceTree. Shortly after opening VS, Git works; shortly after closing it, Git doesn't work.

Listing the versions since the software is old and updating it is a struggle:

- Git - 2.12.2.windows.1
- Visual Studio Code - 1.19.1
- SourceTree - 1.10.23.1
- Visual Studio 2017 - 15.0.0+26228.13

Any advice or help on how to further debug this would also be greatly appreciated. The end goal of course is to have all programs be able to perform Git operations independently.

Comment: Please clone it using ssh. See this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565661/414785.

Comment: @Yamato So switch protocols and abandon HTTPS?

Comment: Yes, based on reading about git, ssh is the recommended way of cloning.

Comment: @Yamato No luck. :( Most likely the SSH port hasn't been whitelisted, and I have no clue how long it would take them to open it up.

Comment: Will this help? Set username globally and use credential helper to remember password. https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git

Comment: This also can be a reference, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627954/414785

Comment: @Yamato Credential helper is already on, and auto-fetch is already off. :\