# Github Login Issue with VS code

Tags: git, authentication, github, visual-studio-code

I have to log in again and again whenever I try to push to my repository.

If I untick the above then only it works fine but still it asks me again for username and password which is not ideal.

[image: My VS config]

PC configuration:-
- VSCode Version: 1.45 Debian 
- OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Can you be clearer about what is 'the above'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code always asking for git credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400272/visual-studio-code-always-asking-for-git-credentials)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Github VSCode Docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#github-authentication-for-github-repositories):

**GitHub authentication for GitHub repositories**

VS Code now has automatic GitHub authentication against GitHub repositories. You can now clone, pull, push to and from public and private repositories without configuring any credential manager in your system. Even Git commands invoked in the Integrated Terminal, for example `git push`, are now automatically authenticated against your GitHub account.

You can disable GitHub authentication with the `git.githubAuthentication` setting. You can also disable the terminal authentication integration with the `git.terminalAuthentication` setting.

**UPDATE:** Refer to the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34627954/2054487)

Comment: @KevalKaria If this worked for you, then I would request you to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the case for you, cloning from the `https` rather than the `ssh` is often the source of issues like this one.

Instructions for setting up SSH keys to GitHub:
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Setting up the connection details inside VSCode may interfere with using `git` from a terminal outside of it.