# How to update saved git credentials on Visual Studio Code

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has recently started allowing automatic authentication against GitHub repositories (VS Code version 1.45+). 
[official documentation reference](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#github-authentication-for-github-repositories)

This feature is really useful as it allows the user to save the credentials and avoid entering them repetitively for each commit.

I am on version 1.45.1 and recently I updated my github credentials. Since then the trouble has started for me again. 
Because my previous credentials are saved somewhere for VS Code, my push requests are failing by default:

[image]

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#github-authentication-for-github-repositories), I was able to disable the automatic authentication using the 'git.githubAuthentication' setting:

[image]

Post that VS Code started prompting me for credentials again. However, once I provide the new credentials and authenticate successfully once, I was intuitively expecting that the credentials will now get updated and enabling the 'git.githubAuthentication' setting again should allow me to bypass the credential prompts as previously.

Sadly that has not been the case and I continue to get the same 'Authentication failure' messages again post enabling the setting. Apparently. VS Code is saving the credential details to some specific location and not updating it automatically.

Looking for some help and suggestion on this.

I searched for this issue and was not able to find a possible solution. The closest reference is the post: [visual-studio-code-always-asking-for-git-credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400272/visual-studio-code-always-asking-for-git-credentials) which was the case for versions prior to 1.45.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest update for VS Code - 1.46.1 seems to have got this issue resolved. Post update it asked me for authorising VS Code to access my GitHub and once allowed, it has started working again - no need to login to git again and again for git operations !!.

Answer (score 2):

Doing "git fetch" in vscode terminal will actually pop vscode own input box which will update the credentials globally (atleast on osx).