# Vscode keep asking for authentication after successfully added SSH key

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh, gitlab

I have followed the instruction on gitlab website and have successfully generated and added SSH key to gitlab. However, vs code still keep asking for authentication. I don't want to change `auto-fetch: False` as the accepted answer suggested [Visual Studio Code always asking for git credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400272/visual-studio-code-always-asking-for-git-credentials/50420113#50420113) . How can I fix this problem?

**EDIT:** I tried changing `auto_fetch: false` but vscode still asking for authentication. This happens in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your local repository cloned via SSH? If you cloned it via HTTP, you need to delete it and clone it again using SSH.