# Visual studio code asks for github authentication

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I've been using VS code for about a year now and never had this issue before. I don't know why it started, but about a week ago every time I try to `push` to github VS code is asking for password and git link. I found several other SO questions that are similar (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400272/visual-studio-code-always-asking-for-git-credentials)) and followed their steps. Now the passwords seem to be stored and I don't have to write them every time, but there is still a window that pops up every time I try to `push` :

[image]

I don't want to see any widow or have to write any password (just like it was for almost a year) in order to interact with github.

Comment: Are you using https or ssh?

Comment: Not sure. How do I find that?

Comment: @Penguin From the command line, you can `cd` to the directory with your code then do `git remote -v`.

Comment: With that said, I'm pretty sure you would only see this if you are using `https`. One solution is to use `ssh` instead. You can find instructions how to setup SSH for your github account in the github documentation. Google "github ssh".

Comment: Yea looks like `https`. And like I said, everything was fine for about a year. I don't see a reason to change to `ssh`... There must be some way to fix this?