# how to make git remember your application password

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

Now bitbucket forces me to use a password called app password. They are not username / password, I already have those configured so that it does not ask me for them.
What I want is that every time I do a push it doesn't ask me for this new "application password". This happens to me with the Visual Studio Code IDE and with the Fork tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code is always asking for Git credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400272/visual-studio-code-is-always-asking-for-git-credentials)

Comment: No, that question solves the save username and password. Data that I already have saved. What I need to save is the application password. It's like two-step verification.