# git pull from Visual Studio console opens the authentication window

Tags: git, authentication, visual-studio-code, git-authentication

Git pull from PowerShell works fine but git pull from Visual Studio console opens the authentication window:

[image]

And if I close the window they still ask for username/passwords via commandline:

[image]

How can I get rid of having to authenticate every time from VS.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode may require you to sign in. In the left plane window, there should be a git icon (if there isn't you'll need to download the extension).

Are you sure it isn't just a single sign on request?

Check this out:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/github

Comment: Yes I am sure it's not saving the auth, It's asking every time I launch VS.

Comment: See if this thread helps :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400272/visual-studio-code-is-always-asking-for-git-credentials

Comment: installing vscode:extension/GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github solved it . Thanks.

Comment: actually I was wrong, the extension solved only for VS relaunch cases, not for system restart cases.