# Visual Studio 2019 doesn't remember GitHub credentials

Tags: git, visual-studio-2019

With a clean install of Visual Studio 2019 (Community Edition), every push to a GitHub repo asks for credentials. When I paste in my access token the push succeeds, but I'm asked again on the next push.

[image]

Git credential helpers are supposed to cache your credentials, and Visual Studio 2019 uses the Git Credential Manager (GCM) by default. (I see "GCM" in Git > Settings > Source Control > Git Global Settings > Credential Helper. I see `credential.helper=manager` in `git config --list`.)

No luck with the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34400272/362702) (which is about Visual Studio Code) -- same behavior if I set the credential helper to `store` or `cache` or `wincred` or `manager-core`.

Same behavior if I run from the command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\Git\cmd\git.exe" push
```

(This worked fine for years until I installed Visual Studio 2022, uninstalled it, and reinstalled Visual Studio 2019.)

I've spent half a day on this. Almost ready to go back to SSL (ugh).

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your workspace git config to see if the credential helper or other relevant settings have been overridden?

Comment: Thanks for the thought. Did a fresh clone of repo, and examined global .gitconfig - no luck.

Comment: Be sure to check `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig` as well. In my setup, I see specific settings for ADO and I don't use github. I suspect you might have something there. https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK6DS.png

Comment: @JeffMercado, that was it!! It still had `[credential] helper = manager-core` from my years-ago install. Microsoft changed GCM to use `manager` instead of `manager-core` but reinstalling VS 2019 didn't change that config. If you'd like to make an actual answer I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to check the git config at each level (project, global, and system) to make sure a setting is to be what you expect.

- project - The git config in your current repository directory. The config file will be found in `[repository]/.git/config`.
- global - The git config in your home directory. The config file will be found in `~/.gitconfig`.
- system - The git config in your git install directory. The config file will be found in `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitconfig` for Windows.

You should be able to check settings from the command line as well for each of the different levels.

```
# effective settings (if set in project, global, or system)
$ git config credential.helper

# project settings (if set)
$ git config --local credential.helper

# global settings (if set)
$ git config --global credential.helper

# system settings (if set)
$ git config --system credential.helper
```