# Cannot sign in with GitHub in VSCode

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, github

I'm new to stackoverflow, so appologies in advance.

I'm having trouble with signing in GitHub in VSCode on Windows.
When i attempt to Sign in with GitHub to use [GitHub Pull Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3I4G.png) and Issues', it get's stuck with the status showing:
['Signing in to github.com...'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzUrV.png)

The GitHub Authentication output shows:
2024-02-27 10:54:46.102 [info] Logging in for the following scopes: read:user repo user:email workflow
2024-02-27 10:54:46.110 [info] Trying without local server... (read:user repo user:email workflow)

Eventually it stops and i get the status:
[You have not yet finished authorizing this extension to use GitHub. Would you like to try a different way? (local server).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe6YM.png)

Pressing Yes to the prompt simply restarts the whole process, resulting in the same issue.

It should be noted that i am using a virtual machine.

I'm at a loss on what to do, so any help is appreciated.

I've attempted various ways to sign in, and searching through similar issues, it seems VSCode is not opening browser windows when it should.

Comment: Seems authorization not granted when [the extension asks the first time](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/github#_authenticating-with-an-existing-repository). Typically, Windows stores the Git credentials in "Windows Credentials Manager". You can take a look at it, if the right creds are stored.

Comment: Hello Deepak, thanks for the answer.
How do i know if the right creds are stored? When i open the manager, it seems no credentials are currently stored.

Comment: You can force Windows to store the credentials by setting `credentials.helper` config, [as answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298381/6519224).

Comment: It seems i can change the credential.helper to 'store' correctly, but running:
git push http://example.com/repo.git (changed to my own repo)
Simply gives me another prompt to sign in (The extension 'GitHub wants to sign in using GitHub'), repeating the process of it attempting and failing to sign in.


As far as I've understood, from reading about similar issues, it sounds like a browser window is supposed to pop up, prompting me to enter my credentials, once i try to connect, which does not happen despite having checked that there are no stored github credentials in the manager.

Comment: Not in Windows, I think. Maybe you've check the   credentials you're trying. I would suggest you use command line ( git bash) to the verify authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm already using a git bash terminal in VSCode and have tried to set my user.name, user.email and even a personal token with github.token, but the problem persists.