# Why can't I see any branch in git?

Tags: git, github

When I try the `git branch` command to see a list of my branches, I can't see any thing. Snapshot:

[image]

As you can see, the commands `git branch` and `git branch -v` do not show a list of branches as they are supposed to.

***`Details`***: I have been messing around with my repository for some time now. My repo's github webpage says that branch `hw3` is 17 commits ahead of master.

Is it because I have deleted everything from branch `hw`' in my local repo?

Also, when I try the command `git checkout master`, I get the following message:

```
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

As of now, I have deleted everything in the `hw`' branch on my machine, but the Github webpage still shows all those files.

Also, I typed in the command `git init` while in the `hw3` branch as a suggestion from another question on stackoverflow. How will this affect me?

Initially, I had a bunch of files in my `hw3` branch and just a README file in my master branch. I just want things to get back to normal.

How should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn I think, this might solve your problem!!

Comment: if you don't have any local changes you might loose, you can also just delete the whole folder (containing .git/ and all your files) and clone it again from the repository (on server).

Answer (score 10):

`git branch` without any parameters only print out the local branches.

#### ***`git branch`*** common options:

```bash
# print out local branches
git branch   

# print out remote branches
git branch -r

# print out local & remote branches
git branch -a
```

---

#### How to resolve your problem

First of all update your local repo with the remote repo

```
git fetch --all --prune
```

Now checkout any branch you need

```
git checkout master
```