# "git checkout -- [repository and file]" => "error: pathspec '[repository and file]' did not match any file(s) known to git"

Tags: git

On a git project, I ve been working from two different machines. I updated a same file on those 2 different machines. It raises conflicts on `git pull`. So I try to do a `git checkout` of the file that raises the conflicts but the `checkout` of the file never succeed.

**In detail:**

I want to `pull` on machine B the last update made on machine A, and `push`-ed from machine A to git repository Branch `master`. Last update situation has change on file `src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts`, it happens that I have also made some changes on that same file on Machine B (the one I want to update with repo content).

**Step 1:** From machine B. If I do a `git fetch`, ([as advised here to solve the issue I get in my title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn?answertab=votes#tab-top)) and `git pull`, I get:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
>
> ```
>    src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts
> ```
>
> Please move or remove them before you can merge.
>
> Aborting

**Step 2:** If I launch a `git status` on machine B, I get:

> On branch master
>
> Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
>     (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
>
> Untracked files:
>
> (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>   src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/
> ```
>
> nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

**Step 3:** Then I launch `git checkout -- "src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts"`, it says:

> error: pathspec 'src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Whatever `get checkout -- [something]` I launched, I've tried with: `.`, `src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts` (as shown above), `src/custom-pipes/.`,`src/custom-pipes/my-pipe`,`src/custom-pipes/.`. It works and says nothing, if the `my-pipe` is not mentioned in what has to be `checkout`. Or throw the error message like that:

> error: pathspec 'src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>   If `my-pipe`, `my-pipe/.` or `my-pipe/my-pipe.ts` is involved in the path to checkout.

I any case, If I go back to **Step 1** and I try to launch `git fetch` and `git pull` afterwards it does not `pull` and throws:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
>
> ```
>    src/custom-pipes/my-pipe/my-pipe.ts
> ```
>
> Please move or remove them before you can merge.
>
> Aborting

Any advise?

**UPDATE**: I managed to make it work by removing **without git** the [repository and file] that were causing conflict. Then `git pull` went smooth afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by removing without git the [repository and file] that were causing conflict. Then `git pull` went smooth afterwards.