# Git: Checking out file from master always gets 'did not match any files(s)'

Tags: git, github

I realised I accidentally edited a file I wasn't meant to a few commits ago. I want to revert this file to the original on master. To that affect I have tried:

`git checkout master -- path/to/file.ext`

`git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file.ext`

`git checkout origin/master path/to/file.ext`

`git fetch && git checkout origin/master path/to/file.ext`

But for each I've gotten the error "did not match any file(s) known to git." (this file does exist on master).

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt looks the closest:

```
git checkout master -- path/to/file.ext
```

I don't know whether this even be valid, but in any case you should be checking out from four commits before the current `master`.  Try the following:

```
git checkout <SHA-1> -- path/to/file.ext
```

Where `<SHA-1>` is the hash of the earlier commit in `master` whose version you want to restore.

If you wanted to undo that entire commit, then a possibly nicer thing to do would be to just revert that entire commit, e.g.

```
git revert <SHA-1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those should have worked, as I described in "[How to get just one file from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364223/6309)".
You also have `git show` commands.

But if you get "did not match any file(s) known to git.", that should mean the file is somehow different from `file.ext`: possible a [lowercase/upercase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066978/6309) small difference in the filename or its path.
That or the [repo was a shallow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39143510/6309).