# git - could not checkout remote branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a repo which has a lot of branchs(200+).

And I cloned it using `git clone xxxx.git`

But when I show branches, it only shows few:

```
$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

When I trying to checkout a remote branch `origin/release-1.6.2`, it says no such branch(it exactly exists in my gitlab's web page).

[image]

```
$ git checkout origin/release-1.6.2
error: pathspec 'origin/release-1.6.2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

when I trying to fetch this branch, it seems this branch really exists.

```
$ git fetch origin origin/release-1.6.2
From gitlab.alipay-inc.com:blink/blink-tables
 * remote-tracking branch  origin/release-1.6.2 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

so how can I checkout this remote branch correctly?

it's different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn), because I can not even see the branch in `git branch -a`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: cannot checkout branch - error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn)

Comment: Are you sure it's not a tag?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen No, it is in the `branch` tag in web page.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the correct repo? Perhaps you should clone it again and test it.

Comment: what is the o/p of this command. Can you confirm if anyone had not modifies the behaviour of git branch $git branch -r

Comment: @Stony Yes, I'm using the url provided in gitlab's web page. I've tried more than 3 times.

Comment: @Bijendra what do you mean by "o/p"? `git branch -r ` shows exactly the same result with `git branch -a` excepting the branch `master`.

Comment: Can you checkout the exact commit (`186eafef`)?

Comment: @bimlas Yes, I can checkout this commit. But why checking out branch doesn't work?

Comment: When checked out, run `git describe` - it shows the tags of the commit. If it's contains `release-1.6.2`, then it's a tag. If not, then it's merged and the branch is deleted in my opinion.

Comment: ... I see some confusion: did you named the branch exactly as `origin/release-1.6.2` instead of `release-1.6.2`?

Comment: @bimlas Exactly `origin/release-1.6.2`. I asked my partner, He says it's a mirror branch to another repo.

Comment: If the answer is yes, then you can checkout as `git checkout origin/origin/release-1.6.2`, but you should rename it on the local repo (`git branch -m release-1.6.2`), push it (`git push`) and delete the previous branch from remote (`git push origin :origin/origin/relase-1.6.2`).

Answer (score 2):

You named the branch incorrectly: GitLab shows `origin/release-1.6.2` in the list of branches, thus the branch name is **exactly** `origin/release-1.6.2`. If you want to checkout, use

```
$ git checkout origin/origin/relase-1.6.2
```

To avoid confusion, remove the leading `origin/` in the branch name by

- renaming the local branch

  `$ git branch -m origin/release-1.6.2 release-1.6.2`
- deleting the remote branch

  `$ git push origin :origin/origin/release-1.6.2`
- pushing the renamed branch

  `$ git push origin release-1.6.2`

You can earn the branch (`release-1.6.2`) on the remote (`origin`) as `origin/release-1.6.2`).

Comment: Ah, good catch. Note that you have a typo in your branches as you've written it "relase", with a missing e, but good catch on the `origin/` actually being part of the *remote* branch name.