# Gitlab Shell error updating from 10.5 to 10.6

Tags: git, gitlab, updates

I’m having trouble upgrading my gitlab CE from 10.5 to 10.6 following the guide instructions.

When I type the command:

```
git checkout v$(< /home/git/gitlab/GITLAB_SHELL_VERSION)
```

I receive the error:

```
pathspec ‘v6.0.4’ did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Before this error I checkout gitlab to version 10.6, fetch gitlab shell with

```
git fetch --all --tags --prune
```

but I can’t see the version 6.0.4 available and that’s why I got this error. Gitlab shell last version available is 6.0.3.

Is there anything I have to do to get v6.0.4 available for checkout and proceed with the upgrade to gitlab 10.6?

Thank you

Comment: can you take a look: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn)

Comment: I finally resolved this issue updating gitlab shell remote from github to gitlab. git remote set-url origin https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell.git and then fetching the repo i get the version 6.0.4 and I finally can go on with the upgrade.