# Git fetch does not resolve pathspec error on git checkout -- *

Tags: git, git-checkout

In previous projects, I often run `git checkout -- *` to discard all changes in my working directory.

1. In my current project, I get the following:

   ```
   $ git checkout -- *
   error: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any file(s) known to git.
   ```
2. I then do a `git status`:

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch <feature_branch>
   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/<feature_branch>' by 2 commits.
     (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

   Changes not staged for commit:
     (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
     (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

       modified:   <relative_file_path_in_current_app_dir>

   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
   ```
3. I read another StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn/7334027) that said `git fetch` can resolve this pathspec error. I tried that and it puled a new feature branch from remote:

   ```
   $ git fetch
   remote: Counting objects: 67, done.
   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
   remote: Total 67 (delta 55), reused 0 (delta 0)
   Unpacking objects: 100% (67/67), done.
   From https://bitbucket.org/<repo_name>
      b42b31e05..e7f3858ad  <unrelated_bug_branch>       -> origin/<unrelated_bug_branch>
      36b2cd4e9..ac87583fd  develop                      -> origin/develop
      61945b8ef..22a63fd7e  <unrelated_feature_1_branch> -> origin/<unrelated_feature_branch>
      322a39980..1f8752f2c  <unrelated_feature_2_branch> -> origin/<unrelated_feature_2_branch>
    * [new branch]          <unrelated_feature_3_branch> -> origin/<unrelated_feature_3_branch>
      5fe02b8b3..a27140571  <unrelated_feature_4_branch> -> origin/<unrelated_feature_4_branch>
   ```
4. I do another `git status` and it's the same as #2 above.
5. I can target the specific file and that will work:

   ```
   $ git checkout -- <relative_file_path_in_current_app_dir>
   ```
6. `git status` now shows I have a clean working tree.

What exactly is the root cause of my pathspec error and how can I resolve it? I can checkout specific files in the meantime, but I'm just curious about this error.

Comment: Good question, and the other question to which you linked is surprisingly void of explanations, yet full of possible fixes.  Question for you: Did you do anything unusual to the single file which is showing up as changed?  I would look into this while you're waiting for help here.

Comment: I guess `node_modules` is an ignored file/directory. You could use `git checkout -- .` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid the linked question [Git: cannot checkout branch - error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5989592/1256452) is a mess: as you noted, it has a lot of answers, and little explication.  Meanwhile [ElpieKay's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749222/git-fetch-does-not-resolve-pathspec-error-on-git-checkout#comment90460301_51749222) has the right answer: `node_modules` is a file or directory that you are having your Git ignore, so when you ask your Git to update it, it says: *Huh?  Update what now?*

#### The long description

The root of the problem stems from Git cramming too many things into one command.  The `git checkout` command can:

- automatically create a new branch (a new branch *name* like `develop` for instance) from some existing remote-tracking name like `origin/develop`; or
- check out an existing branch (a branch with a given *name*, like `master`); or
- check out an existing historic commit (by *tag name* like `v1.2` for instance, or by raw hash ID), resulting in what Git calls a *detached HEAD*.

All of these actions move your Git's notion of `HEAD` in some way.  The special name `HEAD` (all capital letters—this is generally required on Linux systems, while Windows users can often get away with typing `head` in lowercase) is how your Git remembers *which branch you are on, if any*.  Hence, the above three kinds of `git checkout` change *which branch you are on*, or—for the scary-sounding, but actually pretty normal internally,<sup>1</sup> detached HEAD case, the lack-of-any-branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git uses this detached HEAD state when you are in a conflicted or interactive rebase, for instance.  It's not a good idea to use it for normal development, but it's fine for temporary work, or for these internal-to-Git states.  Just finish up your rebase, or whatever it is that has resulted in a temporarily detached HEAD, and Git will re-attach HEAD and you can proceed to walk around with your head firmly reconnected. :-)

---

But `git checkout` can do a bunch more things that *don't* involve changing your `HEAD` at all, and that's what `git checkout --` is for.  Here, Git can:

- extract one or more files from your *index* to your *work-tree:* `git checkout -- filename(s)`, or
- extract one or more files from a specific commit, writing it first to your index and then to your work-tree: `git checkout commit-specifier -- filename(s)`.

The `--` separates the commit specifier, such as `master` or `develop` or `1f3a907` or whatever, from the file name.  The `--` is often *required* if the file is named `master`: `git checkout master` would switch your `HEAD` to `master`, rather than checking out the *file* named `master`.  It is sometimes optional: if you have a file named `master` but you want to get the copy out of the tip of `develop`, writing `git checkout develop master` makes this clear to Git (even if it leaves ordinary humans confused).

There are even more things that `git checkout` can do, but let's stop with just these three sets of clearly very-different operations: (1) *change HEAD to a different branch*, (2) *change HEAD to be detached on a specific commit*, and (3) *don't change HEAD at all, just get me a file, or several files, from the index or from a specific commit*.

Git expresses these different actions with various syntax markers in [the `git checkout` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html).  Quoting from that—I'll quote the whole scary seven-item list that's in there—we see:

> *git checkout* [`-q`] [`-f`] [`-m`] [`<branch>`]
>   *git checkout* [`-q`] [`-f`] [`-m`] `--detach` [`<branch>`]
>   *git checkout* [`-q`] [`-f`] [`-m`] [`--detach`] `<commit>`
>   *git checkout* [`-q`] [`-f`] [`-m`] [[`-b` | `-B` | `--orphan`] `<new_branch>` [`<start_point>`]
>   *git checkout* [`-f` | `--ours` | `--theirs` | `-m` | `--conflict=<style>`] [`<tree-ish>`] [`--`] `<paths>...`
>   *git checkout* [`<tree-ish>`] [`--`] `<pathspec>...`
>   *git checkout* (`-p` | `--patch`) [`<tree-ish>`] [`--`] [`<paths>...`]

Three of these are the operations we're talking about in this answer (the other four are yet *more* things that `git checkout` can do, some of which maybe should be different Git commands).  Let's go through them.

#### Checking out a branch by name (or checking out a commit and detaching HEAD)

Start with the the first line:

> *git checkout* [`<branch>`]

(I left out the options to simplify it).  This shows the branch name in angle brackets, meaning you should fill one in.  It's in square brackets as well, so you can leave it out, but if you *do* leave it out, it means "stay on the current branch", which is kind of a silly thing to do.  Putting the word `branch` in angle-brackets like this marks it as what some call a *meta-variable*, i.e., something you should fill in, with the *name* of the meta-variable telling you what *kinds of things* go here: branch names!

This is the *switch to some existing branch, or create a new branch from some existing remote-tracking name* operation.  The branch name you give is the branch name to switch to, or to automatically create.  Git will look for an existing branch with that name, and if it cannot find one, will look through all your *remote-tracking* names—your `origin/master`, `origin/develop`, and so on—to see if one of *those* names can have `origin/` removed and be the name you asked for.

(The second quoted line is like the first one, but with `--detach` inserted.  The third line is like the first two, but instead of `<branch>` it says `<commit>`.  In the second command line, `--detach` is required, and in the third, it's optional again.  The `<commit>` meta-variable means that you can use anything that names a commit, not just a branch name.  These are the variants that produce a detached HEAD: they check out a commit the same way switching branches would, but they chop your HEAD off in the process, so that you are on *no* branch.  Essentially, if you give `git checkout` an argument that names a commit but is not a branch name, Git just assumes you *meant* `--detach`.  If you want to detach while using a branch name, you must add `--detach`.  This last thing is not something most people want to do, but the manual page covers it anyway.)

**The linked question and its answers are mostly about *creating a new branch from a remote-tracking name*.**  That is, they answer the question:

> *If I say `git checkout feature-X` I get an error, but then I run `git fetch`, and do `git checkout feature-X` again, and it works.  Why?*

The answer here is that the first time you ran `git checkout develop`, you *didn't* have an `origin/feature-X`, but after `git fetch` finished, you *did* have an `origin/feature-X`.  That, in turn, is because `git fetch` created it, because *someone else* created `feature-X` on `origin`, some time relatively recently.  The `git fetch` has your Git call up the Git at `origin` and get a list of all its branches and commits.  Your Git loads up all their new commits that you did not have yet, and creates or updates all your `origin/*` names, and now you have `origin/feature-X`.

#### Check out specific files

The second-to-last quoted syntax line:

> *git checkout* [`<tree-ish>`] [`--`] `<pathspec>...`

shows two meta-variables.  The first one is spelled `<tree-ish>`, which is Git shorthand for: *You can use a branch name here, or a commit hash, or anything that I can use to find what I call a tree object.*  Git has a *lot* of ways to specify commit hash IDs, and this is meant to cover all of them, plus some more weird corner cases you're unlikely to encounter.  This first meta-variable is optional, and if you leave it out, Git will check files out from Git's *index* (which we have not really described here, and I won't go into details as this is already plenty long).

The second meta-variable is `<pathspec>`.  Note that it is *not* optional!  This is Git-speak shorthand for *the name of a file, or a pattern with `*`, or any of a lot of other things that are also too long to go into here.*  The `...` part means you can list more than one of them.  These *pathspecs* name the *specific file or files* that you want Git to find in the `<tree-ish>` (the commit you named, if you named one).

#### Where everything went wrong

When you write:

```
git checkout -- *
```

your shell—probably `bash`—expands the `*` to match all the files in your current working directory.<sup>2</sup>  So if you have files `README` and `hello` and `node_modules` and so on, what *Git* sees is:

```
git checkout -- README hello node_modules ...
```

There is no `<tree-ish>`, so Git looks in your index for files named `README`, `hello`, `node_modules`, and so on.

If it doesn't *find* one of these—and it doesn't find `node_modules`—Git complains:

> ```
> error: pathspec 'node_modules' did not match any file(s) known to git.
> ```

and does nothing.

If you instead use `.`, your shell runs:

```
git checkout -- .
```

and Git sees `.` as the `<pathspec>` argument.  This means "all the files known to Git in the current directory", so that will do what you wanted.  You could also write:

```
git checkout -- '*'
```

which uses quote marks to protect the `*` from `bash` (or whatever shell you are using).  Then *Git* will see the `*` and *Git* will expand `*` to "all the files known to Git in the current directory".  But writing `.` is easier.

---

<sup>2</sup>Note that on Windows, CMD.EXE *doesn't* expand the `*`, instead passing it to Git, letting *Git* expand the `*`, and this error never happens!

Comment: Wow. Thank you for a fantastic, comprehensive write-up and answer. This definitely inspires me to further understand all the magic that `git` does behind the scenes (and also `bash`).