# How do I remove a branch in GitBash?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-bash, git-commit

```
Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi)
```

Hii, I am new to GitHub and I want to know that what is this, and why it is showing every time and how can I remove it? (add-hemang-joshi) is in green colour in GitBash. See the image as well.

I tried using:

```
git branch -D add-hemang-joshi
```

but didn't work and showed an error viz.

```
error: Cannot delete branch 'add-hemang-joshi' checked out at 'C:/Users/7386-856
15SG 2913642'
```

[image: My gitBash looks like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't delete a branch sitting on that branch. So, you need to checkout to another branch then delete the branch.

```
$ git checkout master
```

If `master` branch does not exist in your local then create and checkout to a new branch (e.g. add-hemang-joshi_2):

```
$ git checkout -b add-hemang-joshi_2
```

Delete the branch `add-hemang-joshi`:

```
$ git branch -D add-hemang-joshi  # delete the branch

$ git branch                      # check if the branch is deleted
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but I encountered an error


error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git

Comment: @HemangJoshi  try `git fetch` and then make a checkout. A post related to your error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn

Comment: Still, no change 
```Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi)
$ git fetch

Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi)
$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: @HemangJoshi ok, could you try create and checkout to a new branch: $ git checkout -b add-hemang-joshi_2  $ git branch -D add-hemang-joshi

Comment: @HemangJoshi did you set the origin with the remote URL? what is the output of $ git branch -a ?

Comment: @HemangJoshi: you need to give `git checkout` the name of some branch that it understands. This would normally be the same name as some *remote-tracking name* that `git branch -r` would print out, minus the `origin/` part. Your `origin` repository might have `main` instead of `master`, for instance.

Comment: @SajibKhan I created that new branch and switched to it. But when I did Delete operation for first branch, it was showing an error ```error: branch 'add-hemang-joshi' not found.
```
git branch -a is not even showing any output
```Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi_2)
$ git branch -a

Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi_2)
$```

Comment: @torek git branch -r is not showing any kind of output. 
```Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi_2)
$ git branch -r

Hemang Joshi@SOLO MINGW64 ~ (add-hemang-joshi_2)
$```

Comment: @HemangJoshi since you are getting the following error that means your branch `add-hemang-joshi`has been deleted already!
`"error: branch 'add-hemang-joshi' not found"`

Comment: @SajibKhan Yeah, I guess it's deleted!!, but now I cannot delete this add-hemang-joshi-2 and I cannot even checkout to the master branch. So what shall I do?

Comment: @HemangJoshi you need to set a remote like `$ git remote add origin <your_remote_url>` then `$ git fetch` then `$ git checkout master` then try to delete the branch in same way!

Comment: @SajibKhan It worked!! I know stackoverflow doesn't recommend saying thanks, but I need to say. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 5):

You couldn't delete the branch you are on currently. So checkout to the other branch and then delete the required branch.

```
git checkout master
```

The above command switches to the master branch.

```
git branch -d add-hemang-joshi
```

The above command would delete the `add-hemang-joshi` branch.

Adding to the above

The `-d` option will delete the branch only if it has already been pushed and merged with the remote branch.
The `-D` is to force delete a branch even if it hasn't been pushed or merged yet.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete the branch on which you currently are.

First switch to another branch.