# fatal: pathspec 'origin' did not match any files

Tags: git

I have an error named in the title.

```
fatal: pathspec 'origin' did not match any files
```

It happened when I tried to change remote repository from new to old one. There are no changes comparing with old version. Last commits are same in local and remote repositories.

I used `git add origin` command.
It was my mistake in command.

Does anybody have such problem? How to solve it?

Comment: what command exactly did you try to run?

Comment: Paste the command in the question, please, not as a comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: cannot checkout branch - error: pathspec '...' did not match any file(s) known to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989592/git-cannot-checkout-branch-error-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files-kn)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I used `git add origin` command

[`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) is for adding files.

[`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem) is for adding remote URL:

```
git remote add origin https://....
```

Comment: I saw it when review mu command. But thanks))

Comment: @Cherik No problem, that will help others.