# SourceTree: dst ref refs/heads/master receives from more than one src

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, atlassian-sourcetree

I don't understand this git (sent via SourceTree) error, and I have no idea why it is happening. I simply commit to my own repository, working alone on the project. What could i try to do?

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master using_php_inside:master
Pushing to https://github.com/sl5net/SL5_AHK_Refactor_engine
error: dst ref refs/heads/master receives from more than one src.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sl5net/SL5_AHK_Refactor_engine'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git 1.8: it push error: dst ref refs/heads/master receives from more than one src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373528/git-1-8-it-push-error-dst-ref-refs-heads-master-receives-from-more-than-one-sr)

Answer (score 0):

It seems your pushing from your local master to remote master and the same time, your local using_php_inside branch to remote master.

Try to not selecting your other local branch when pushing. The problem can be due to how you have configure your sourcetree client.

Comment: now i pulled and merged (lost 11days work but could use actual backup ;).  committed and pushed. that works (but without binary data :( and i am not able to delete the branch using_php_inside. <p> i using phpDesktop inside

Comment: In command line go to you local repository directory and type 'git branch -D using_php_inside' For binaries data it is manage by your .gitignore file open it and edit it at your convenience

Comment: git branch -D using_php_inside says: Cannot delete the branch <branch_name> which you are currently working on.
then i checkout. but same error again. checkout everywhere. same error.

Comment: If your working on your current branch, to delete, but if this is your choice, just stash or discard your changes before checking out another branch. ''git stash" and after "'git checkout master". And from there you should be able to delete your former branch. And after all that, just apply your stash to you master branch

Comment: thanks. now it works. thanks for your help. and in windows7 (os here) there is a global gitignore_global.txt far away from project repository. i found it. dlls are now online. thank