# origin/, remotes/origin/ Git confusion

Tags: git, repository, branch

I just cloned a repo and started a new branch in Git. I have done this many times without encountering a problem. Tonight when I tried using `git branch --set-upstream develop origin/develop` to set the upstream location, I got this error:

```
fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/develop'.
```

Reading around suggests that this is a result of the same branch name existing in both the origin, and the remotes/origin. I don't understand the difference between these two, and why they would conflict this way. I typed `git branch -a`, and this was the output:

```
* develop
  master
  origin/develop
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
  remotes/origin/master
```

I'm confused about what the difference is between `origin/develop` and `remotes/origin/develop`, and why that would cause the `fatal: Ambiguous object name: 'origin/develop'.` error.

Answer (score 2):

I think that, by mistake maybe, you have a local branch called `origin/master`. Try running `git branch`. If there's a `origin/master` branch listed there, that's it.

See if you should delete that branch. If you can't or don't want to, run `git branch --set-upstream develop remotes/origin/develop` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm  `origin/develop` is the name of a *local* branch instead of a reference to a *remote* one (like `remotes/origin/develop`)

And branches can have a '/' in their name: their are called "hierarchical branch names" (see "[Using the slash character in Git branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309)").
As explained in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Branch-names-with-slashes-td7092954.html), that prevents you to chose "develop" as a branch name. You need to rename it

```
 git branch -m origin/develop develop
 git branch --set-upstream develop origin/develop
```