# How can I tell Jenkins to compile some, but not all branches of a repository?

Tags: git, jenkins

At my place of work, we use a 2 letter coded naming convention when creating git branches.
For example, feature Apple, might be ftr_ap_hotfix  and feature Orange might be done in branch ftr_or_hotfix.

I want to create two separate jobs in Jenkins.  One job should compile all branches that match the name `**_ap_**`  and the other job should compile all branches that match the name `**_or_**`

However, when I set this up, Jenkins is compiling all branches no matter their name.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

The only help I get from the Jenkins page is as follows:

> Specify the
>   branches if you'd like to track a specific branch in a repository. If
>   left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built. The
>   syntax is of the form: REPOSITORYNAME/BRANCH. In addition, BRANCH is
>   recognized as a shorthand of */BRANCH, `'*'` is recognized as a
>   wildcard, and `'**'` is recognized as wildcard that includes the
>   separator '/'. Therefore, `origin/branches*` would match
>   origin/branches-foo but not origin/branches/foo, while
>   `origin/branches**` would match both origin/branches-foo and
>   origin/branches/foo.

Comment: Did you try other patterns, like '`*_ap_*`'?

Comment: @VonC Yes, I also tried `*/*_ap_*`

Comment: It might be possible that it would work only for hierarchical branch names (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309): `feature/**`, instead of part of a branch name. Any chance to rename your branches `ftr/or/hotfix` and see if `**/or/**` works better? Or `ftr_or/hotfix`, and the pattern '`ftr_or/**`'

Comment: Umm.. I had no idea you could put "/" inside a branch name. However, changing the naming structure would involve a company wide change and isn't likely to happen.

Comment: Sure, but that would be just for a test, to see if Jenkin behaves with that kind of naming convention. You can create a branch on top of the existing branch, and then delete that new branch (without any impact to the existing branch).

Comment: @VonC I will try, but look at my edit to the question.

Comment: It seems to me that jenkins can only handle one * or ** in the expression.

Comment: @VonC your comment and suggestion works, I suggest turning it into an answer. Reading more comments now, I'll try again with two usages of `**` or `*`

Comment: @Sg1team and @VonC `*/or/*` worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[As commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817602/how-can-i-tell-jenkins-to-compile-some-but-not-all-branches-of-a-repository/13820639#comment19015143_13817602), It might be possible that it would work only for **[hierarchical branch names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309)**:

```
feature/**
```

, instead of part of a branch name.
So a naming convention like:

- `ftr/or/hotfix`, with pattern '`*/or/*`' or '`**/or/**`'
- `ftr_or/hotfix`, with pattern '`ftr_or/**`'

could work better.