# git remote show origin anomaly

Tags: git

My colleague has a repository and doing:

`$ git remote show origin` outputs:

```
* remote origin
  ...
  Remote branches:
     ...
     DowSzkDoZgl    tracked
     IR-Prod        tracked
     ...
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
     DowSzkDoZgl    merges with remote origin/DowSzkDoZgl
     IR-Prod        merges with remote IR-Prod
     ...
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
     DowSzkDoZgl    pushes to DowSzkDoZgl         (up to date)
     IR-Prod        pushes to IR-Prod             (local out of date)
     ...
```

The anomaly appears on the line *after* `Local branches configured for 'git pull':`

`DowSzkDoZgl    merges with remote origin/DowSzkDoZgl`

Specifically, `origin/DowSzkDoZgl`.

Why does it specify *origin/* in front of the remote branch name?  None of the other Pull Config branches have this AND we're already "inside" of *origin* so it seems redundant.

**EDIT**
git config:

```
[branch "DowSzkDoZgl"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/origin/DowSzkDoZgl

[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: It is likely that the remote branch name is actually `origin/DowSzkDoZgl`.  This is still a valid branch name.  What do you see in `.git/config` under the `[remote "origin"]` section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would reference a branch named '`origin/DowSzkDoZgl`' instead of `DowSzkDoZgl` (that is, a [hierarchical branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309), which include a '`/`')

Try reset the [upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089294/git-why-do-i-need-to-do-set-upstream-all-the-time) with a:

```
git branch -u origin/DowSzkDoZgl DowSzkDoZgl
```

(if it complains there is already an upstream, precede that command with a `git branch --unset-upstream DowSzkDoZgl`)

Comment: my colleague has confirmed that the branch on the remote repo is indeed `origin/DowSzkDoZgl`.  So, why is the remote-tracking branch named/setup as just `DowSzkDoZgl`?

Comment: @jberger1st generally, the *local* branch is correctly named, but incorrectly pushed: `git push origin origin/DowSzkDoZgl` instead of `git push -u origin DowSzkDoZgl`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: local branch = `DowSzkDoZgl`; local remote-tracking branch = `DowSzkDoZgl`; remote branch (on the remote repo identified as _origin_) = `origin/DowSzkDoZgl`.

Comment: @jberger1st true, that must be the remote origin which must be incorrectly defined, then.

Comment: another peculiar issue.. under _Local refs configured for 'git push'_, git displays `DowSzkDoZgl pushes to DowSzkDoZgl (up to date)`.  However, shouldn't it read `DowSzkDoZgl pushes to origin/DowSzkDoZgl`?

Comment: @jberger yes, it should, unless it consider '`origin`' as being the default remote name and not display it.