# Creating a remote inside a directory of remotes

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am working on a project with multiple contributors who work on adding new features.  When I `git branch -a`, it shows something like this:

```
remotes/origin/usr/username1/featureA
remotes/origin/usr/username2/featureB
remotes/origin/usr/username2/featureC
remotes/origin/usr/username2/featureD
remotes/origin/usr/username3/featureE
```

Local changes are pushed to these remotes before they are reviewed and merged with the master release branch.  How can I create a remote that is also in this format, with my username and my feature name? Also, is this a path with directories for each user or is it just a string containing a slash?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I create a remote that is also in this format, with my username and my feature name?

You don't: Other would add your repo as a remote (an [upstream repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)), and fetch your branch, which will be listed for them as their branches is listed for you.
That is: if you create a branch with '/' in it: it is called [hierarchical branch names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309)

```
git checkout -b usr/myusername/featureX
```

[Jakub Narębski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/46058/jakub-narebski) does mention though:
"One caveat is that you can't have both branch '`foo`' and branch '`foo/bar`' in repository."

> is this a path with directories for each user or is it just a string containing a slash?

The latter, it defines a branch name with namespaces.

This is often see in gitolite-managed git repositories, with a feature like "**[personal branches](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/special.html#pers)**".