# Maintaining a fork of a Git project

Tags: git

Let's say that I'm working on a project with a team, and I have some home-made patches I use in development (you might say I have a fork of the project). I'd like these patches to be available for myself but they should not be checked into the team's repo, and it should still be easy to contribute to the original project. How would I manage this?

Currently I'm using some `.diff` files that are filtered out by using git's `update-index --skip-worktree`, and then I have created a custom tool around this. I'm just wondering if there's already some tooling solved the problem in a better way?

Comment: Isn't it something what you can manage with bit.dev? It is a cool tool at least for UI components' sync between projects.

Comment: Just commit your personal changes to your personal repository, or in a personal branch, and don't share this branch with the rest of the world?

Comment: @Grav I have this same question. Closest answer I am currently able to find is following in the footsteps of this solution (treat your local branch as a fork and treat remote as the original repo): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471151/git-workflow-for-maintaining-a-derivative-fork However it still requires having a custom tool so its not much of an improvement over your existing solution.