# Pushing to Pull Request Branch on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've got a project where somebody has submitted a pull request. I locally made some commits to that pull request, and even succeed in pushing them to the pull request branch on GitHub. You can see that pr/1 is well ahead of the initial pull request.

https://github.com/uwdub/web-dub-importer-dblp/network

But the code that would be merged by the request is still back at the original pull. My commits are not being added as part of it.

https://github.com/uwdub/web-dub-importer-dblp/pull/1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The pull request asks to pull changes from the branch master of the repo of tonyinsect. You made changes to the branch pr/1 of the repo of uwdub.

Comment: I have a pull request. I like part of what is in that request, but I can't pull it in its current form. I could just tell the person to do it differently. But in this case, I'm trying to push some commits myself to help get it in the state that I want it.


How do I do that process? Help in improving the pull request to the point that it can be integrated into the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned by @JBNizet,

The pull request in question is in repo from `tonyinsect:master` into `uwdub:master`, while you have made changes to branch `uwdub:pr/1` (i.e your own repo).

You can either push the changes to `tonyinsect:master` (if you've the permission), or ask the other guy to fetch new branches from your repo, and merge in your changes in his branch. He needs to do the following

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com/uwdub/web-dub-importer-dblp.git
git fetch upstream
git checkout master && git merge upstream/master
git push origin master
```

Once he does these steps, his pull request will automatically be updated.

Worst case, you can do away with his pull request and pull in changes directly from his repo, as below:

```
git remote add downstream https://github.com/tonyinsect/web-dub-importer-dblp.git
git fetch downstream
git checkout pr/1 && git merge downstream/master
#Check if everything is allright
git checkout master && git merge pr/1
git push origin master
```

PS: I would suggest avoiding usage of `/` in naming of branches, it might lead to issues like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527452/1860929)