# git branch --merged is showing remote

Tags: git, git-branch

When I run `git branch --merged` it shows:

```
* master
remote/master
```

Should it be showing `remote/master` in the list?

If it is down to settings, then how do I change things to stop showing this in the list?

Comment: I thought the proper notation for remote branches was remotes/<remote-name>/<branch-name> ... what does `git branch -a` show?

Comment: Do you have color enabled? If so, what color is it? If it is not red then it just means that you have a _local_ branch named remote/master.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, remote/master would be the name of a local branch, since [you can use slash in the name of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309).

> It is possible to have hierarchical branch names (branch names with slash). For example in my repository I have such branch(es). One caveat is that you can't have both branch 'foo' and branch 'foo/bar' in repository.

The remote tracking branches are in their own namespace:

```
 remotes/<remotename>/abranch
```

So it is possible you have a *local* branch named `remote/master`, which has been merged to `master`.