# Git: What is the best way to pull a remote branch?

Tags: git

This sounds a very simple question about git however the reason I am asking this is because I've faced some issues/troubles when tried to pull a remote branch.

My colleague created a branch called `feature/branch-A` and pushed that branch to remote.

So now I have to finish some tasks he had started on that branch. Now it comes the question: What is the best way for me to pull `feature/branch-A` ?

Comment: what do you mean by **best way to pull** either use directly pull command or fetch and apply the changes.

Comment: What issues/troubles? People can't help you if you don't explain what's not working.

Comment: git pull; git checkout branch-A

Comment: Sometimes slashes in branch names have issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527355/using-the-slash-character-in-git-branch-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a way to acquire a local copy of a remote branch to work on:

`git checkout -b localbranch origin/path/to/branch`

This will create a new branch named `localbranch` locally set up to track the branch `path/to/branch` from the origin, and switch to it immediately. You can name it whatever you like, but personally I usually name it exactly the same as the origin. Alternatively you could separate out the commands if you want to do things step by step:

```
git branch localbranch origin/path/to/branch
git checkout localbranch
```

The first command here creates the local branch, and sets it up to track the remote branch, but does not switch to it. These are the ways to create a local branch that tracks a remote branch. `git pull` and `git push` are used afterwards to sync snapshots. I would definitely recommend reading through the git tutorial to get a better understanding of all this: https://git-scm.com/doc.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to do a `git fetch` so that your local git repository is aware of the new branch your colleague has created and pushed to origin. Then you just simply `git checkout feature/branch-A`. Git will assume you're referring to the same branch that is on remote and will switch to that branch which it now has a reference to.