# Can we combine git tags?

Tags: git, github, git-tag

Here is my use case:

1. I am working on feature-branches that are common throughout the platform.
2. But there are certain feature-branches that are specific to some use cases, for eg:

   ```
   feature-branch1
     use-case1
       commit1
       commit2
       commit3
     use-case2
       commit1
     use-case3
       commit1
       commit2
   ```
3. Also, each branch is associated with a version, like v1.1, etc.
4. Intuitively, I am thinking of git tags, but I've only seen them used for sem-versioning.
5. For my use case listed above, can I combine git tags? For eg.:

   ```
   feature-branch1
     use-case1 v1.1 (2 tags)
     use-case3 use-case4 v2.3 (3 tags)
     use-case10, use-case11, use-case12 v5.6 (2 tags)
   ```

Can it be done using git tags? If not, how should I achieve my use-case?

Comment: Thank you @SergioTulentsev for formatting my question, I was trying to format the text as a code, but it was just not working for in my StackOverflow editor.

Comment: When putting code in a list item, indent it with additional 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use branch namespace instead.
That means feature1 becomes 3 branches:

```
feature1/use-case1
feature1/use-case2
feature1/use-casen
```

Then you can update each branch individually with new commits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @vonc. Sorry for my late reply, I was waiting on more answers. Where can I find more online on branch namespacing?
Also, won't tags have any use here?

Comment: @viraj.kulkarni http://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309: branches allows for new commits to be created. tags refers to one commit and are immutable. If you are working on feature branches, using branches is appropriate.