# Difference between "upstream" branch and branch with owner's name

Tags: git, github, branch, git-branch, git-fork

In the process of learning Github, I forked my friend's repository to work on some of the code. I cloned the fork to my computer and added the upstream remote so I could update my repository with his. Now when I view my branches with `git branch` in Git Shell, it shows 5 branches: my own master, 2 from upstream, and then 2 more. These two are the same as the two upstream ones, but instead of "upstream" it says my friend's name. What's the difference between these two branches and the two upstream branches?

I'm referring to the first two in the following picture.
[image: Branches]

Comment: Perhaps `git branch -av` tells you more?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see after cloning a fork and adding upstream (original repo)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git
> git clone https://github.com/VonC/gitpitch-docker
Cloning into 'gitpitch-docker'...
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 3), reused 13 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (13/13), done.

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git
> cd gitpitch-docker

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\gitpitch-docker
> git remote add upstream https://github.com/fukusukei/gitpitch-docker

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\gitpitch-docker
> git fetch upstream
From https://github.com/fukusukei/gitpitch-docker
 * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master

vonc@VONCAVN7 D:\git\gitpitch-docker
> git br -avv
* master                  a21fb40 [origin/master] update
  remotes/origin/HEAD     -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master   a21fb40 update
  remotes/upstream/master a21fb40 update
```

You should see branches starting with origin (your fork) or upstream (the original repo).

By default, cloning a fork shows remote branches as `origin/xxx`.

But if `git branch` (*not* `git branch - r` or `-a`, so *local* branches only) shows you `jenilajmera/xxx` branches, that simply their names: [you can name a branch with a '`/`' in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309).

Comment: I do see them, but I see others as well, which I didn't add.

Comment: @RohanKhajuria What `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: @RohanKhajuria That is the name of local branches apparently. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309) Check instead the output of `git branch -avv`