# Unable to trigger builds for "release/" branches

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins

We have branches set up like this:

- origin/develop
- origin/release/1.0.0
- origin/release/1.1.0

### Bitbucket

In the BitBucket, we have added Hook called "Bitbucket Server Webhooks to Jenkins" & Automatic merging is enabled.

Under the Advanced Configuration:

Branch Options is set to `All` and `refs/remotes/origin/develop refs/remotes/origin/release/*` in the input box.

### Jenkins

For Jenkins, under "Source Code Management" section and "Branches to Build" option we have added the following:

```
Branch Specific (blank for 'any'): ${Branch}
Branch Specific (blank for 'any'): **release/*
```

### Problem

Jenkins picks up build when we push to develop. Nothing happens when we push to any of the release branches.

Also tried manually: http://server/job/Jenkins%20Bitbucket%20Test/buildWithParameters?Branch=release/1.0.0, but this triggers a build for release/1.1.0 and not release 1.0.0.

Comment: Did you try mentioning the `branch` as `**release/*` ?

Comment: yes sorry that was typo

Comment: [once look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/5003256). Make sure you are not doing that. And try `**/release/**` this `/` might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The syntax is of the form: `REPOSITORYNAME/BRANCH`. In
>   addition, `BRANCH` is recognized as a shorthand of `*/BRANCH`, `*` is
>   recognized as a wildcard, and `**` is recognized as wildcard that
>   includes the separator `/`. Therefore, `origin/branches*` would match
>   `origin/branches-foo` but not `origin/branches/foo`, while
>   `origin/branches**` would match both `origin/branches-foo` and
>   `origin/branches/foo`.

Therefore my `**release/*` needs to be `*release/**`