# Naming convention to warn that branch is likely to be rebased

Tags: git, branch, naming-conventions, rebase

I sometimes push branches to a publicly-accessible repository (e.g. github) knowing that they contain half-baked commits, works in progress, and other sorts of things that are very likely to be rebased.

Is there a generally-understood naming convention that would serve to warn those cloning my repo that this branch is not a good one to build their work upon?

I know I can put warnings in the commits on these branches, but I'm looking for a convention for the branches themselves.

Comment: Start them all out `WIP/`?  Kinda winging it here.

Comment: I voted to reopen this one. The question is very clear and not opinion based. *"Is there a generally-understood naming convention that would ..."* is an easy yes/no question. And the answer is no, cause there is no generally accepted naming convention for this. How you should handle this in the absence of an accepted naming convention is, however, an opinion based question, but that's not OP:s question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a generally-understood naming convention that would serve to warn those cloning my repo that this branch is not a good one to build their work upon?

No, nothing official.

The only norm is that `master` is supposed to be ready to run.

Since [you can use / in the name of a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527436/6309), jthill's comment is as good an option as any: a `WIP/xxx` namespace.