# Git branching creating issue: "fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/"

Tags: git, git-branch

I have branch name **develop_native/** and from that creating another branch name **develop_native/feature/** but it is throwing error:

> fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/develop_native/feature':
>   'refs/heads/develop_native' exists; cannot create
>   'refs/heads/develop_native/feature'

Anybody know what could be possible issue ?

Comment: You cannot create a branch with a slash in the name if the part before the slash already exists as a branch. This is explained in the proposed duplicate I linked.

Comment: In particular, see this answer: [You can't have both a file, and a directory with the same name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527355/using-the-slash-character-in-git-branch-name/2527452#2527452).