# Name conflicts with refs/heads/release when trying to create release/ branch

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm trying to create `release/0.1.0` branch in Azure DevOps repo but getting error `Name conflicts with refs/heads/release`:
[image]

It doesn't matter based on what branch I'm trying to create,
it also works fine when I'm trying to create `feature/0.1.0` branch

Is it a king of a permissions issue (I'm not admin in this Azure DevOps project)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the slash character in Git branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527355/using-the-slash-character-in-git-branch-name)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is purely a Git restriction. You can't create a branch "under" another branch.

You could create `releases/0.1.0`. But since there is already a `release` branch, you can't put a new branch underneath it.

Observe:

> `git status`

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

> `git checkout -b master/foo`

```
fatal: cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/master/foo': 'refs/heads/master' exists; 
cannot create 'refs/heads/master/foo'
```

Comment: If you have lots of git branches with the same naming pattern, it's possible to batch rename git branches stackoverflow.com/a/44570815/3281978

Answer (score 6):

A git limitation due to how Git store references as files (and folder tree) in the `.git/refs/heads` folder.

When you trying to create the branch `release/0.1.0`, Git tries to create the folder `release` to create a file named `0.1.0` inside it.

Because there is already a file named `release` corresponding to the branch already created, Git can't create a folder with the same name (the file system doesn't allow it).

Due to this limitation linked to how git handles ref through the file system, git doesn't allow this case and verify this type of case when you try to create it (even if refs are packed).